# How to call multiple statements when setting a value for an object property in an object initializer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

If the property to be calculated only requires one statement, it is pretty simple

```
let object = {
    array: new Array(10)
};
```

Alternatively I can also do the following (though I don't like it as much)

```
let object = {};
object.array = new Array(10);
```

But what if I want to (e.g.) initialize the array with values of 0 (by deafult the values are "undefined")? I can only do it the second way

```
let object = {};
object.array = new Array(10);
for(let element of array){
    element = 0;
}
```

The closest thing to the first method that comes to mind might be doing something like this

```
let object = {
    array: (function(){
        let array = new Array(10);
        for(let element of array){
            element = 0;
        }
        return array;
    })()
}
```

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this that I do not know of?

Edit: The array was just the first thing that came to mind when thinking of an example. My problem does not lie exclusively on initializing an array, I am looking for a more general solution than using Array.fill().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing an Array with a Single Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049847/initializing-an-array-with-a-single-value)

Comment: @HaoWu sadly, no. I just edited my question to explain why.

Comment: @DarkRebellion can you think of a slightly more complex example of what you might need to do? I think your question might essentially just be equivalent to: "what clever and concise one-liners can I do?"

Comment: @AndrewParks my example is already complex, I just didn't know that there is a library function that already does this... Let's say, I don't want to change the entire array to 0, but only the value of the 4th and 7th element, and everything else remains as is. I'm hoping there isn't another existing function that can do this as well haha...

Comment: @AndrewParks I would rather only use one-liners because I find the code simple, rather than because the syntax forces me to... Otherwise it might hurt my readability of the code later on

Comment: @DarkRebellion I added an example of setting indices 4 and 7 differently. It really does look like your question is too dependent on the specific goal you want to achieve and whether there is a concise one-liner possible

Comment: @DarkRebellion I added a way to use arrow functions and comma expressions, which you might find useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IIFE to perform more complex inline calculation of property values from within an object initializer. As an example based on the posted code:

```js
const obj = {
    array: (()=> { // example code
        const a = new Array(10);
        return a.fill(0);
     })(),
    hw: "hello world",
}

console.log(obj.hw, obj.array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Array.fill:

```js
let object = {
  array: Array(10).fill(0)
}
console.log(object)
```

Or, to do a slightly more complex array initialization:

```js
let object = {
  array: Array(10).fill().map((_,i) => `hello ${i}`)
}
console.log(object)
```

To initialize an array of length 10, with the number 1, except in indices 4 and 7:

```js
let object = {
  array: Array(10).fill(1).map((e,i) => [4, 7].includes(i) ? 0 : e)
}
console.log(object)
```

You can also use arrow functions and comma expressions (but it can easily start to become unreadable). Note that the arrow function declares parameters that it can use as variables, instead of having to do `let x =` , which would require braces.

```js
let object = {
  array: (x => (x = new Array(10).fill(), x.forEach((e,i) => x[i] = Math.random()), x))()
}
console.log(object)
```

I recommend that instead of doing complex one-liners, you create your own separate helper functions. This will maximise code readability. For example, you could create a helper function called `function createArrayWithRandomValues(length, upperBound)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to fill array with `0` as:

> The `fill()` method of Array instances changes all elements within a range of indices in an array to a static value. It returns the modified array.

```js
let object = {
  array: Array(10).fill(0)
};

console.log(object);
```

Also, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) as:

> The `Array.from()` static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable or array-like object.

```js
let object = {
    array: Array.from({ length: 10 }).fill(0)
};

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to initialize an array. Here are some examples based on your requirements:

1. Using `Array.fill`

This is useful if your array consists a single value

```js
let object = {
  array: Array(10).fill(0)
}
console.log(object);
```

2. Using `Array.from`

This is useful if want your array elements based on their original value or indices.

```js
let object = {
  array: Array.from({ length: 10 }, (element, i) => i)
}
console.log(object);
```

3. Using generators

This is useful if you want to dynamically control how your array is formed.

```js
let object = {
  array: [...function*() {
    yield 'T-MINUS';
    for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      yield i;
      
      if (i === 7) {
        yield '7 is my favorite number btw'
      }
    }
    yield 'LAUNCH';
  }()]
}
console.log(object);
```

---

4. Using `Array.with`

This is useful for "*I don't want to change the entire array to 0, but only the value of the 4th and 7th element*"

```js
let object = {
  array: new Array(10).with(3, 0).with(6, 0)
}

console.log(object);
```