# Javascript: How to merge the string values of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, underscore.js, chromium

I want to use the [_.zip function of Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#zip) to create pairs from two arrays.

```
var a = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];
var b = ["one", "two", "three"];
var pairs = _.zip(a, b);
alert("pairs = " + pairs);
```

This seems to work fine when [done with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134020/356895) however when [using strings](http://jsfiddle.net/nmR7b/) the result is confusing:

> pairs = 3,3,3,3,3,3

Instead I expect the following result:

> pairs = [["alpha", "one"], ["beta", "two"], ["gamma","three"]]

**Update:**
Thanks to the comments I discovered that the described behavior does apply to **Chromium** running on Ubuntu. However the expected result is return when I run the same script in Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: It's definitely confusing, because [this code does not produce that result](http://jsfiddle.net/t3XvH/1/).

Comment: It worked for me. (Edited the above to use strings, still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nmR7b/1/)

Comment: Works fine under XUbuntu 13.04, Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 13.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu3). The jsFiddle that izuriel posted alerts with `(alpha, one),(beta, two),(gamma, three)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [filed a bug](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/1105) for the problem.