# What is the most efficient way of merging [1,2] and [7,8] into [[1,7], [2,8]]

Tags: javascript

Given 2 arrays [1,2] and [7,8] what is the most efficient way of merging that to form [[1,7], [2,8]]. I know we can do this:

```
a1 = [1,2], a2 = [7,8], a3=[];
for (var i=0; i<a1.length; i++) {
  a3.push([a1[i], a2[i]]);
}
```

I am dealing with a large array. So I want to see if there is a better way.

Comment: AFAIK, you're doing it well :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this faster than O(n) because every element must be touched once.

Answer (score 5):

That is a good question!

First off, make sure that you assign `a1,a2,a3` to the local scope via the `var` keyword, which it seems you forgot. Otherwise performance can suffer tremendously.

As for the code-performance comparison. You can test/see the results [here](http://jsperf.com/zip-speed-difference):

[image: zip tests]

**pure JavaScript:**

```
var a1 = [1, 2],
  a2 = [7, 8],
  a3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
  a3.push([a1[i], a2[i]]);
}
```

**JS/Native methods:**

```
var a1 = [1, 2],
  a2 = [7, 8],
  a3 = [];
a3 = a1.map(function(e, i, a) {
  return [e, a2[i]]
})
```

Of course there are more possible implementations, but the point is that probably no other implementation can beat a for-loop and straightforward packing, in *O(n)*-time as kindly pointed out by Travis J.

Engine/Optimized: V8 JavaScript Engine via *Chrome v29*

Answer (score 1):

You are basically searching for a function identical to Python's `zip` function, so check out the answers to an older SO question:

[Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-funciton)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's about as efficient as it gets.  It's running in *O(n)* time.  Really not much more you could ask.  If there's anything you could optimize, it would be transforming a1 into a map, but that's optimization for memory, and it sounds like you want to speed things up intstead.