# Extract ids from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of db records that I want to convert from this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

To this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
}
```

I'm looking for the fastest performing/easiest solution to this.

I couldn't find any PHP functions for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On PHP 5.5 or later, the simplest solution would be using PHP's built-in [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) function.

```
$ids = array_column($arr, 'ID');
```

Comment: @ChrisForrence They are now. :)

Comment: Nice solution! But this available only in PHP 5.5+

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk That's worth mentioning, indeed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$bas = array();
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    $bas[] = $bar['ID'];
}

print_r($bas);
```

Where `$foo` would be you original array and `$bas` the one you want to convert it to.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote simple test for finding best solution between those:

```
// foreach
foreach ($array as $element) { $result[] = $element['ID']; }
// array_map
array_map(function($element) { return $element['ID']; }, $array);
// array_push
foreach ($array as $element) { array_push($result, $element['ID']); }
```

**Results:**

```
Test name   Repeats         Result          Performance    
foreach     1000            0,009204 sec    +0% 
array_push  1000            0,015731 sec    -70,915%
array_map   1000            0,024891 sec    -170,437%
```

From time to time they are slightly different, but `foreach` is always the best with outstanding performance results. So, seems @campari answer must be best answer. But i did not tested @kba solution, cause i'm on PHP 5.4. I suspect that `array_column` algorithm will show superior results.

Test code here: [link](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/ExtractIdFromMultiDimArr.php).

Comment: Thanks. I suspected so. See these performance figures for JavaScript's `map` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293378/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-merging-1-2-and-7-8-into-1-7-2-8/17910641#17910641). Though, if you can afford it, `array_map` is definitely a powerful and convenient choice, that can make use of its own stack-allocation - of course managing that "extravagance" is a crux when it comes to speed.

Answer (score 2):

Your **input data** (enriched with other data-types, -for testing-) and assuming you are using recent PHP versions:

```
$input = array(
    0=>
    array(
        "ID"=>  "2"
    ),
    1=>
    array(
        "ID"=>  "3"
    ),
    "iamnotanarray", 100, null
);
```

**exemplary:**

```
$out = array_map( function($el){ return @current($el);}, $input);
```

**generally:**

```
$out = array_combine(
    array_keys($ret)
    ,array_map( function($el){ return @current($el);}, $ret)
)
```

**output:**

```
var_export($out);

array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => '3',
    2 => NULL,
    3 => NULL,
    4 => NULL,
)

var_dump($out);

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  NULL
  [4]=>
  NULL
}
```

To filter potentially unwanted data types, you may use:

```
$out = array_filter($out, is_string);
var_dump($out);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

I didn't time it (*yet*), but this is using **PHP's native** precompiled functions. Speed varies with the gcc compiler optimizations of your PHP executable.

*Note:* `@current` is dirty, not recommended and just used for brevity/readability. It would yield the same effect as `is_array($el) ? current($el) : NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($array as $a)  // $array is original array 
{
    array_push($newArr, $a["ID"]);
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: Hint: PHP has a function for that already called [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column). In case you don't have PHP 5.5, there is a userland equivalent: http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/