# Sorting an array according to another array's sorted index

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays. I should do a normal sort on one (descending or ascending) and sort the other according to how the first array is sorted. This is because each element in the first array has a relationship with the same index element on the second array, and I must keep this relationship true. For example:

```
sortThis=[3,1,2];
sortAccording=["With 3","With 1","With 2];
```

I couldn't find any way to take the index changes from JavaScript's `sort` function.

Comment: do they have to be in separate arrays?

Comment: they are separate when i take them and i must output two separate arrays as well. but if merging and splitting them again solves the problem then its good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**
To achieve that, you have to **zip** both arrays in just one. This is, given you have this two array:

```
sortThis=[3,1,2];
sortAccording=["With 3","With 1","With 2];
```

After **zip** them, you will have the following array:

```
zipped = [{a: 3, b: "With 3"}, {a: 1, b: "With 1"}, {a: 2, b: "With 2"}];
```

Then, you sort it by **a** in order to have:

```
zippedAndSorted = [{a: 1, b: "With 1"}, {a: 2, b: "With 2"}, {a: 3, b: "With 3"}];
```

**What next?**

Well, once you have this array sorted by what you want, you have to extract their values with the **map** function and finnaly you will have your two arrays sorted by the same criteria:

**The code:**

```
// your arrays
sortThis=[3,1,2];
sortAccording=["With 3","With 1","With 2"];

// the zip function    
function zip(a,b) {
    return a.map(function(aa, i){ return { i: aa, j: b[i]};} )
};               

// ziping and sorting the arrays
var zipped = zip(sortThis, sortAccording);
zippedAndSorted = zipped.sort(function(a,b){ return a.i - b.i; });

// your two sorted arrays
sortedThis = zippedAndSorted.map(function(a){ return a.i;});
sortedAccording = zippedAndSorted.map(function(a){ return a.j;});
```

You also can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/cfpcJ/

Good luck!

Comment: Using objects in `zip` is hardly a good idea. You'd be better off with array of arrays - this way both sorting and "unzipping" can be greatly simplified.

Comment: @thg435: What's the difference? An array is just an object with numerical properties, and it would not be used differently in the code here. Theoretically, you'd need a tuple.

Comment: @Bergi: the difference is that javascript knows how to sort a multidimensional array.

Comment: @thg435: Huh, what? No, it does not. You still would need the custom compare function, especially when sorting numbers like the OP.

Comment: How could javascript know that?

Comment: @Bergi: try that in your browser `javascript:alert([[4,5],[2,3],[0,1]].sort())`

Comment: @thg435: Then try `[[2,0],[10,1]].sort()` or `[["a",0], ["b",1], ["a,a",2],["a,_",3]].sort()`

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
function zip(a, b) {
    var i = 0, j = 0, r = [];
    while(i < a.length && j < b.length)
        r.push([a[i++], b[j++]]);
    return r;
}

function unzip(r) {
    var a = [], b = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        a.push(r[i][0]);
        b.push(r[i][1]);
    }
    return [a, b];
}

r = zip(sortAccording, sortThis);
r.sort();
r = unzip(r);

sortAccording = r[0]
sortThis = r[1]
```

Another way:

```
result = sortAccording.
    map(function(elem, pos) { return [elem, pos]}).
    sort().
    map(function(elem) { return sortThis[elem[1]]})
```

Better implementations of zip and unzip (both working with variable number of arguments):

```
zip = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return args[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return args.map(function(a) {
            return a[i]
        })
    })
}

unzip = function(a) {
    return a[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return a.reduce(function(y, e) {
            return y.concat(e[i])
        }, [])
    })
}
```

Comment: In your `zip` function, isn't `i` always equal to `j`?  If so, why not omit `j`?

Comment: @Andomar: good call! Here's [a nicer implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/989121)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to this. Create a third array of indexes. Just sort that index array based on the sort of first array.

```
  var indexArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < sortThis.length; i++) {
    indexArray[i] = i;
  }

  indexArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (sortThis[a] > sortThis[b]) ? 1 : (sortThis[a] === sortThis[b]) ? 0 : -1;
  });

  // Now you have the sorted index ready
  console.log("The first elements in the arrays are: " + sortThis(indexArray[0]) + " and " +  sortAccording(indexArray[0]));
```