# How to join two arrays into one two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays. How can I join them into one multidimensional array?

The first array is:

```
var arrayA = ['Jhon, Connor, 12, 62626262662', 
              'Lisa, Ann, 43, 672536452', 
              'Sophie, Lynn, 23, 636366363'];
```

My other array has the values:

```
var arrayB = ['Jhon', 'Lisa', 'Sophie'];
```

How could I get an array with this format??

```
var jarray = [['Jhon', ['Jhon, Connor, 12, 62626262662']], 
              ['Lisa', ['Lisa, Ann, 43, 672536452']], 
              ['Sohphie', ['Sophie, Lynn, 23, 636366363']]]
```

Comment: This is called "zipping", here's the [javascript implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/989121).

Comment: Thanks for this question ... Helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var jarray = [];
for (var i=0; i<arrayA.length && i<arrayB.length; i++)
    jarray[i] = [arrayB[i], [arrayA[i]]];
```

However, I wouldn't call that "multidimensional array" - that usually refers to arrays that include items of the same type. Also I'm not sure why you want the second part of your arrays be an one-element array.

Comment: Though you'd want to make sure the arrays are of equal length (or use the length of the smaller one).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I already use the length of the smaller one. Of course, a `for (var i=0, l=Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length); i<l; i++)` might have been more elegant.

Comment: Ah, I see I had interchanged them. Fixed now.

Comment: @FelixKling: You think the OP actually had more than 3 strings in his `arrayA`? Yes, then you would need to adapt my solution a bit.

Comment: Oh damn... I'm so sorry, I did not notice that those are three strings. I thought the array contains 12 elements! So sorry :-/ Will delete all my comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a map version

```js
const arrayA = ['Jhon, kend, 12, 62626262662', 
              'Lisa, Ann, 43, 672536452', 
              'Sophie, Lynn, 23, 636366363'];

const arrayB = ['Jhon', 'Lisa', 'Sophie']; 

/*  expected output
    var jarray = [['Jhon', ['Jhon, kend, 12, 62626262662']], 
                 ['Lisa', ['Lisa, Ann, 43, 672536452']], 
                 ['Sohphie', ['Sophie, Lynn, 23, 636366363']]] */
              
 const jarray = arrayB.map((item,i) => [item,[arrayA[i]]]); 

 console.log(jarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/#find
Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that passes a truth test (iterator). The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element, and doesn't traverse the entire list.

```
var even = _.find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> 2
```

Then, you can make the same with the array B elements and by code, make a join.

Comment: Hmm, really no. Because, he need find elements in the arrays A and B. And if he make a for (var i=0; i<arrayB.length;i++) he can know the names of elements in this array. with underscore, he can find and asociate this elements

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get what you were asking:

```
var jarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    jarray[i] = [];
    jarray[i].push(arrayB[i]);
    var valuesList = [],
        comparator = new RegExp(arrayB[i]);
    for (var e = 0; e < arrayA.length; e++) {       
        if (comparator.test(arrayA[e])) {
            valuesList.push(arrayA[e]);
       }        
    }
    jarray[i].push(valuesList);
}
```