# Combine two arrays into one array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays currently

```
array1 = [5, 10, 20]
array2 = [10, 20, 30]
```

Either array3 or something like this:

```
array4 = [{"a":5, "b":10}, {"a":10, "b":20}, {"a":20, "b":30}]
```

I know this is probably an easy question but I'm not even sure what array3 would be called so its kind of hard to google this.

Comment: That's not even a valid result.

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717/989121

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very simple, first we create a result array, then we iterate through the first array and add elements to it. [**Here is a working fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6caH/)

Note, in your code you have notation like `{5,10}` which is illegal in JavaScript, I assumed you mean an array.

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
   result.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
}
```

**Update after edit** , it seems like you want objects, try

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
   result.push({a:array1[i],b:array2[i]});//add object literal
}
```

If you'd like, you can also use `map` and write the same code functionally. [Here is a fiddle of that sort of implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/AXc4c/)

Answer (score 2):

This is called `zip`...

```
function zip() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var shortest = args.length==0 ? [] : args.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a.length<b.length ? a : b
    });

    return shortest.map(function(_,i){
        return args.map(function(array){return array[i]})
    });
}
```

Check [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) a fantastic js library with many of these utility functions...

Comment: Note, this will fail on many browsers since it relies on methods such as `reduce` and `map` which need to be shimmed first.

Comment: @thg435 Yes, I mean IE8, IE7 and IE6 which are sadly still widely used (IE6 is still over 20% of chine :( ) . I think the answer is ok, however anyone using this code should be aware of the need to shim map and reduce if you intend to support some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a new ES6 feature.

```
var array1 = [5, 10, 20];
var array2 = [10, 20, 30];
var combineArray = [...array1 , ...array2];
//output should be like this of combine array : [5, 10, 20, 10, 20, 30]
```

If you want to extra item inside two array then you can do this using below way:

```
var combineArray = [...array1, 333, ...array2];
//output should be like this of combine array : [5, 10, 20, 333, 10, 20, 30]
```