# How to apply function to n-th element of two arrays (array of arrays)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Suppose I have two arrays (A and B) which are to be arguments to a function taking two values as arguments (a and b).

**How can I use the function and the arrays in such a way that I obtain another array C that stores the result of putting the n-th element of A together with the n-th element of B into the function ...**

```
var A = [1,2,3,4];
var B = [1,2,3,4];

function myFunction(a,b)
{
return a+b ;
}
```

**C** than should be something like:

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: What would `a` and `b` equal in this example?

Comment: To get the n-th element of an array it's just `myArray[n]`. Here, you could do `A[n]+B[n]`. Put that in a for loop for the length of A/B and iterate n.

Comment: @tymeJV : I do not really understand the question ... a and b are the parameters of myFunction, so the values to put in are supposed to be the A[0], B[0] than A[1], B[1] than B[2], B[3] ... is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean given that example, what are `a` and `b`, are they `0,0` `1,0` -- I just don't see what you're doing to get that output

Comment: @tymeJV It's pretty clear. The input is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and the result should be `[2, 4, 6, 8]` based on that `myFunction` is applied to each pair of the input.

Comment: @deceze -- I'm an idiot. Was thinking something extremely complicated when it was not :\ -- damnit brain.

Comment: I sum the first element of A and the first element of B than I take the next pair of elements and so on ... it perfectly makes sense in other languages I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a simple `for`-loop:

```
var C = new Array(A.length);
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{
    C[i] = myFunction(A[i], B[i]);
}
```

Or using the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method (although see [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map)):

```
var C = A.map(function(a, i) { return myFunction(a, B[i]); });
```

Comment: I realy like usage of map instead of using a loop ... but is'nt there a way to put e.g. A and B together and than map? ... something like: ``var AB = [A,B];`` ``AB.map(myFunction)`` ??

Comment: @marvin_dpr Unfortunately no. `map` considers one array, and only one item at a time from that array.

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly knows as "[zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#g:19)" and can be implemented like so:

```
function zipWith(a, b, callback) {
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i++) {
        // if (typeof b[i] == 'undefined') throw some error or break, your choice
        c.push(callback(a[i], b[i]));
    }
    return c;
}

c = zipWith(A, B, myFunction);
```

Comment: [See this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)