# Combine arrays into an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays:

```
dates = ['2013-06-01', '2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-10-01', '2013-11-01']
values = [20, 10, 5, 5, 20, 25]
```

What I need to do is merge them into this format:

```
data: [
  { date: '2013-06-01', value: 20 },
  { date: '2013-07-01', value: 10 },
  { date: '2013-08-01', value: 5 },
  { date: '2013-09-01', value: 5 },
  { date: '2013-10-01', value: 20 },
  { date: '2013-11-01', value: 25 }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. What have you tried so far? Do you know how to iterate over arrays?

Comment: First think about how to merge the data structure in javascript. JSON is just a serialization format and is a trivial last step.  Can you show the code you have tried to merge these array into an array of objects?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they're always the same length:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.date = dates[i];
    obj.value = values[i];
    data.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm. I'm sure you already thought of this. using jquery, apologize if you don't use this.

```
 data = jQuery.map(dates,function(v,i){
      return {'date': i, 'value': values[i]}
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't produce what the OP wants. Where are you using `values`?

Comment: i was running late and didn't remember what the array names where. I edited in the correct one

Comment: It's still not correct though. I think you want `'date': v` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
  data: dates.map(function(x, i) {
    return { date: x, value: values[i] };
  })
};
```

Array.prototype.map is ECMAScript 5th Edition and doesn't work in < IE9.
For older browsers us [this polyfill](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/2.0.8/es5-shim.min.js)

Answer (score -1):

If jQuery is an option, you can try this:

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: `serializeArray` is used to extract the values of a set of form control elements into an array. I don't see how this is relevant here.