# Merge two arrays into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

How can I merge two javascript array, for example:
`[0,1,2,3,4]`
and
`[5,6,7,8,9]`

when merged, result in:

`[[0,5], [1,6], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9]]`

the most optimized way possible, even using the "map" or specific methods.

Comment: @edi9999 it looks simple and basic for you and me. but there are people out there who have just started with these technologies, we should understand them, SO made for all, beginner and expert!

Comment: To add on `@thefourtheye` comment, have a look [at the **answer**. If it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/769678).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4],
    b = [5,6,7,8,9];
Array.prototype.zip = function (arr) {
    return this.map(function (e, i) {
        return [e, arr[i]];
    })
};
```

`a.zip(b)` would give `[[0,5], [1,6], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9]]`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Fxva7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arrFirst = [0,1,2,3,4];
var arrSecond = [5,6,7,8,9];

var arrFinal = [];

$(arrFirst).each(function(index, val){
    arrFinal.push([arrFirst[index], arrSecond[index]]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function constructs a new array, where each key is determined by the callback function you write

```
arrFirst.map(function(value,index){
        return [arrFirst[index],arrSecond[index]];
})
```