# Javascript - zip and sum variable number of arrays in single expression

Tags: javascript, arrays

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/548664) to [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) shows a neat way of taking any number of arrays, and "zipping" them into a merged array in a single statement.

```
zip= rows=>rows[0].map((_,c)=>rows.map(row=>row[c]))
```

This question [Javascript - Sum two arrays in single iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094466/javascript-sum-two-arrays-in-single-iteration) shows a similar idea, but summing the entries as they're zipped up.

I'm wondering how to combine the two techniques - so given an unknown number of arrays:

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3]
]
```

... the result is `[3, 6, 9]`, ie the sum of the first elements, the second and so forth. For the sake of simplicity, assume each array contains the same number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to other answers, it just doesn't have to be so complicated:

```js
numbers = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

var result = numbers[0].map(function(_, i) { 
  return numbers.reduce(function(prev, row) {
    return row[i] + prev;
  }, 0);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First transpose the arrays, so the columns become rows and viceaversa. After that simply call the `reduce` function.

The first version of the code is mostly typescript for brevity. The second version is JavaScript.

Note that ES5 `map` and `reduce` functions are only available on IE9 and higher.

```js
var numbers = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

// TypeScript

var colSums = numbers[0].map(function(col, i) { 
  return numbers.map((row) => row[i]).reduce((a,b) => a + b );
});

// JavaScript

/*var colSums = numbers[0].map(function(col, i) {
  return numbers.map(function(row) {
    return row[i];
  }).reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
  });
});*/
document.getElementById("col-sums").innerHTML = colSums;
```

```html
<p id="col-sums"></p>
```

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea - yours is ES5 compatible (map and reduce available since IE9)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it - this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751601) was helpful - we can extend the original zipping method thus:

```
zip = rows => rows[0].map((_,c) => rows.map(row=>row[c]).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for map, map, reduce, two maps will get you there:

[Quick Demo](https://jsbin.com/jodeci/2/edit?js,console)

```
var m = [
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3]
];

var total = m.map(function(arr, i) {
  var count = 0;
  return arr.map(function(el, idx) {
    return count += m[idx][i];
  })
}).pop()
```

Comment: sorry, that's just going to add the first two, results in [2,4,6]!