# How can I add each value of two arrays together in a third array?

Tags: javascript

Say I have two arrays:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

[[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]]
```

I want to add each value to make:

```
[[2], [4], [4], [7], [9]]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: do you want really an aray in an array?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What has your research come up with? What do your attempts to solve the problem look like?

Comment: Is it array of numbers or array of arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Sum two arrays in single iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094466/javascript-sum-two-arrays-in-single-iteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map()`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    b = [1,2,3,4,5];

a.map(function(v, i) { return v + b[i] });
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks, map() is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through items in array and create your result array on the go.

```
var firstArray = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]];
var secondArray = [[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]];
var thirdArray = [];
firstArray.forEach(function(ele, index){
    thirdArray.push([ele[0] + secondArray[index][0]])
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var res = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;++i)
{
   for(var j=0;j<arr1.length;++j)
      res.push((arr1[i] + arr2[j]));
}
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `map` like so ([demo](https://repl.it/CacI/1))

```
var a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]];
var b = [[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]];

var result = a.map(function(value, index){
    return [a[index][0] + b[index][0]];
});

console.log(result);
```

output

```
[ [ 2 ], [ 4 ], [ 4 ], [ 7 ], [ 9 ] ]
```

**Online Demo - https://repl.it/CacI/1**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [.forEeach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The main differences to notice in this example:

`.map()` returns a new Array of objects created by taking some action on the original item.

`.forEach()` returns nothing, it just iterates the Array performing a given action for each item.

---

Example using .forEach():

```js
var data1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]],
    data2 = [[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]],
    result = [];
data1.forEach(function(item, index){
    result.push([item[0] + data2[index][0]]);
});
console.log(result);
// result = [[2], [4], [4], [7], [9]]
```

Example using .map():

```js
var data1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]],
    data2 = [[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]],
    result;
result = data1.map(function(currentValue, i){
    return [data1[i][0] + data2[i][0]];
});
console.log(result);
// result = [[2], [4], [4], [7], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach` loop on one of the two arrays and do it like this:

```js
var arr1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]];
var arr2 = [[1], [2], [1], [3], [4]];
var sum = [];
arr1.forEach(function(e,i){
  sum.push([e[0]+arr2[i][0]]);
  console.log(sum[i]);
});
```