# How to count elements in 2 different arrays in javascript with same index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 different arrays in javascript, they have always the same length and I need to count one element + another element from another array with same index

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [8, 9, 2];

Expected Output 
1 + 8 = 9
2 + 9 = 11
3 + 2 = 5

let result = [9, 11, 5]
```

What would be the easiest and the most elegant way to do it? I tried for loop and map as well but I didn´t find working solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24094466/7785337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can achieve this with just 1 `map`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [8, 9, 2];

const sums = arr1.map((e,index) => e+arr2[index])

console.log(sums)
```

or a simple for loop

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [8, 9, 2];

const sums = []

for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  sums.push(arr1[i]+arr2[i])
}

console.log(sums)
```

or with a `forEach`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [8, 9, 2];

const sums = []

arr1.forEach((e,index) => {
  sums.push(e+arr2[index])
})

console.log(sums)
```

or with `reduce`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [8, 9, 2];

const sums = arr1.reduce((acc,curr,index) => {
  acc.push(curr+arr2[index])
  return acc
},[])

console.log(sums)
```