# Is there an equivalent to python's zip() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list, for-loop

I have two javascript arrays that I'd like to iterate over simultaneously with a for/in loop. I know how to do this with a normal for loop `for (i = 0; i > number; i++)`. If you're not familiar with python's zip() command, I have an example below.

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,5]
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    print x+y

>>> 4
>>> 7
```

Comment: @iCodez, please point to the question that I've duplicated.

Comment: It's at the top of your question.  Maybe you need to refresh the page?  Either way, here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function

Comment: Yea, I just saw it too. For some reason when it searched for it earlier this question didn't come up. I hate duplicators as much as you do. Sorry about that.