# javascript 2D array from 2 1D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

I would like to know if there is a builtin function of 2D array building from 2 1D arrays.
Of course I can build such function my self but I wonder if there is already array manipulation library.

Example:

input: [1,3,5] and [2,4,6] => [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

Comment: It's a sad world without functional programming to zip.  There's no built-in, but here's a resource that will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're looking for a "zip" function**

*With Underscore.js, zipping arrays made easy*

http://underscorejs.org/#zip

```
var A = [1,3,5];
var B = [2,4,6];
var zipped = _.zip(A,B); // => [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using native JS functions, this is the shortest I can think of right now:

```
var a = [ 1, 3, 5 ],
    b = [ 2, 4, 6 ],
    c = [];

a.map(function(v, i) { c[i] = [v, b[i]]; });
```

It does include a short user-defined function, but *map* allows to significantly simplify the task.

Note that either *a* or *b* could be used as the destination array just as well if you don't mind losing their content.