# Using map and filter on multiple arrays in an object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

Using Wikipedia's API I got an object which looks like that:

```
obj = {["string", Array[10], Array[10], Array[10]]}
```

The first array contains *titles*, second is *descriptions* and third is *links*.

Some of the descriptions may be empty ("").

Example -

[image: Example]

I would like to combine all three arrays into one array as follow:

```
[{title: obj[1][0], desc: obj[2][0], link: obj[3][0]}, ... , {title: array[1][9], desc: obj[2][0], link: obj[3][0]}]
```

But **only combining** if description is not empty - `obj[2][i] !== ""`

I managed to do it using for loop and if:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  if (data[2][i] !== '') {
    arr.push({title: data[1][i], desc:data[2][i], link: data[3][i]});
  }
}
```

Is there a way of achieving the same in a **more elegant way** using javascript's high order function? such as `map` and `filter` (maybe `reduce`?)

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The way I did it in the end was:

```
var resp = ["Football",
  ['Football', 'Soccer'],
  ['FootballDescription', 'SoccerDescription'],
  ['http://football.com', 'http://soccer.com']
];

// Mimic python's zip behavior -> assume arrays are of equal size
function zip(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].map(function(_, i){
    return arrays.map(function(array){
        return array[i];
    });
  });
}

// 1. Throw away the first string, e.g. "Football"
resp.shift();

// 2. Use zip to make an array of intersected arrays, i.e
// [
//   ['Football', 'FootballDescription', 'http://football.com'],
//   ['Soccer', 'SoccerDescription', 'http://soccer.com']
// ]
// and then use map to make each array into a nicely named object
var objects = zip(resp).map(function(x) {
    return ({ name: x[0], desc: x[1], link: x[2] });
});

console.log(objects);
/*
Output:
[ { name: 'Football',
    description: 'FootballDescription',
    link: 'http://football.com' },
  { name: 'Soccer',
    description: 'SoccerDescription',
    link: 'http://soccer.com' } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're about to learn an awesome new higher-order function, *zip*! To be honest, I very rarely run into situtations where it is useful, but your example happens to be perfect for it.

```
/*
 Example in ES6. In order to run, first install node and then go
  npm install -g babel
  npm install underscore
  babel thisfile.js | node
*/

let _ = require('underscore')

let resp = [
  "Football",
  ['Football', 'Soccer'],
  ['FootballDescription', 'SoccerDescription'],
  ['http://football.com', 'http://soccer.com']
]

// 1. Throw away the first string, e.g. "Football"
resp.shift()

// 2. Use zip to make an array of intersected arrays, i.e
// [
//   ['Football', 'FootballDescription', 'http://football.com'],
//   ['Soccer', 'SoccerDescription', 'http://soccer.com']
// ]
// and then use map to make each array into a nicely named object
let objects = _.zip(
  resp[0],
  resp[1],
  resp[2]
).map(x => ({
  name: x[0],
  desc: x[1],
  link: x[2]
}))

console.log(objects)
/*
Output:
[ { name: 'Football',
    description: 'FootballDescription',
    link: 'http://football.com' },
  { name: 'Soccer',
    description: 'SoccerDescription',
    link: 'http://soccer.com' } ]
*/
```

Comment: Brilliant! I combined your answer with the help of - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/3237212, and recieved what I think a nice looking solution :) see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to involve another library if you don't want. Map and filter work here but I think they add a lot of length. I'd favor forEach.

Keep in mind that [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) passes along up to three parameters to your callback function. In this case you can get by with two.

```
data[2].forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem && arr.push({title: data[1][index], desc: elem, link: data[3][index]});
});
```

And a solution using map and filter might look like

```
data[1].map(function(elem, index) {
  return ({
    title: data[1][index],
    description: data[2][index],
    link: data[3][index]
  });
}).filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.description;
});
```

Comment: Seems like I'll stick with the forEach. the Map and Filter just adds extra complexity in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need some lodash/underscore in your life…

http://underscorejs.org/
https://lodash.com/

They are libraries that do exactly that. Take Objects/Arrays and slice and dice them until they are what you want.  Super useful.

Or you could just do it in plain ol' reduce…

```
var crazyArray = ['title here', ['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five'], '', ['six']]
var reduced = crazyArray.reduce(function( last, cur ){
  if(cur) return last.concat(cur);
  return last;
}, []);
console.log(reduced) // [ 'title here', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' ]
```

Comment: I'll check out the underscore.js.