# JavaScript how to map over two arrays one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do have an object which is containing some field, three of them are arrays.
And I would like to map over them in one go.

Let me show how I am doing it right now:

```
containerNames = this.state.fileContent.xContainers.map(xContainer => <Container containerName={xContainer} />);

containerNames.push(this.state.fileContent.yContainers.map(yContainer => <Container containerName={yContainer} />));

containerNames.push(this.state.fileContent.zContainers.map(zContainer => <Container containerName={zContainer} />));
```

For me it does seems like it could be made differently. With one lambda?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937181/javascript-es6-map-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to create an array of arrays, so use a `.map` nested inside another:

```
const { xContainers, yContainers, zContainers } = this.state.fileContent;
containerNames = [xContainers, yContainers, zContainers].map(
  containers => containers.map(container => <Container containerName={container} />)
);
```

Comment: this is still nested.

Comment: OP is looking for an array of arrays, so there's no way to avoid nesting *once*.

Comment: hmm.... I think his original code is doing something  wrong, the first array is not nested but the other two are.

Answer (score 3):

The code in OP will make something like `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, which I hope is not what you want. If you want `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, use this:

```
const containerNames = ["xContainers", "yContainers", "zContainers"].
    flatMap(field => this.state.fileContent[field].map(...));
```

If you want `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, then change the `flatMap` into `map`.

Comment: Nice, I'd do that in a chain rather than nested: `[x,y,z].flatMap(f => fileContent[f]).map(name => etc`

Answer (score 1):

```
const {fileContent : {xContainers, yContainers, zContainers}} = this.state;

const mergedArray = [
   ...xContainers,
   ...yContainers,
   ...zContainers
]

const containerNames = mergedArray.map(container => <Container containerName={container} />)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
containerNames = [...xContainers, ...yContainers, ...zContainers].map(
  containers => containers.map(container => <Container containerName={container} />)
);
```

Comment: Hi, please don't post code-only answers, explain what your code does and why.

Answer (score 1):

In the `mapToContainer` function pass the `c` argument to your `<Container containerName={c} />`

```js
const allow = ['xContainers', 'yContainers', 'zContainers']
const fileContent = {
  xContainers: [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}, {name: '3'}],
  yContainers: [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}, {name: '3'}],
  zContainers: [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}, {name: '3'}],
  foo: {}
}

const mapToContainer = containers => containers.map(c => c.name)

const containerNames = 
  Object.keys(fileContent)
  .filter(k => allow.indexOf(k) !== -1)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...mapToContainer(fileContent[curr])], [])

console.log(containerNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the three arrays and map them you can do it like the following

```
[...xContainers, ...yContainers, ...zContainers].map(c => <Container containerName={c} />)
```

if you're okay with extra libs, you can use lodash

```
_.map(_.concat(xContainers, yContainers, zContainers), c => (<Container containerName={c} />))
```