# Mix two arrays in the given order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, merge, concatenation

Has javascript any inbuilt method Is it possible to merge/combine two arrays in the *same order* as they are? This a basically simple task and could be solved by iterating over the min-length of both and adding each value to the new array:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = [4, 5, 6]
var c = []

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  c.push(a[i])
  c.push(b[i])
}

// => [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

However, I just asked me if that could be done with any inbuilt method. First I thought about `concat` and `sort`, but that feels like *overkill* (in contrast to a loop and performance)...

```
a.concat(b).sort(doItRight)
```

To be a bit more specific, those arrays could contain `strings` and `numbers`...

```
var a = [0, '1', 'c']
var b = ['d', 4, 'f']
var c = [0, 'd', '1', 4, 'c', 'f']
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

**Update**

Just forgot to note that the input arrays could be more more than two. I really like how [reduce works in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676136/1250044), and since the answers in the duplicate question use ugly nested loops, I thought reduce could help?

**Update 2**

There's [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) which could be abused to *zip* strings together:

```
String.raw({ raw: '123 ' }, 4, 5, 6)
// => '142536'
```

Comment: This function is usually called `zip`, it's not built-in in JS, but easy to implement - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717/989121). And you need to flatten the zip result with `[].concat.apply([], zip(arrays))`

Comment: @georg Eh, nope... I just need one array as the result... that's not `zip` ;)

Comment: Yeah, just realized that, reopened and edited the comment. ^^^^

Comment: Yup, saw it... that's in anyway a lot more overkill than *just* `concat`/`sort` :P

Comment: If you're looking for performance, nothing beats a simple for loop.

Comment: You can't use .sort() here, because the order you want doesn't relate to the values themselves, it relates to where the values came from. Just put the loop you've shown in a function and move on - after adding some length checking in case the input arrays have different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in function, but there are more functional ways to do it. Usually, if I've got a working solution of the form "create an array, then loop over something and append to the array", I reach for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead. You can define a `zip` function using `reduce` like so:

```
const zip = (a,b) => a.reduce( (c,x,i) => c.concat(x, b[i]), [] );
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
const zip = (a, b) => a.reduce((c, x, i) => c.concat(x, b[i]), []);
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [4, 5, 6];
console.log( zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) );
//=> [ 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6 ]
console.log( zip([0, '1', 'c'], ['d', 4, 'f']) );
//=> [ 0, 'd', '1', 4, 'c', 'f' ]
```

Comment: ~5 Years to accept your answer... Shame on me!

Comment: only 2 years, actually! And it's never too late. Thank you.