# How to merge two linear arrays into a two-dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example:

```
var array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

How to turn these arrays to `var array = [["one", "1"], ["two", "2"], ["three", "3"]]`?

Comment: This is generally called "zipping" btw.

Comment: use `for` loop to  accomplish this simple task

Comment: So, this question has good answers for you question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717/2544762

Answer (score 7):

```
var array1 = ["one","two","three"],
    array2 = ["1","2","3"],
    newarray = array1.map(function(c, i) { return [ c, array2[i] ] });

alert(JSON.stringify(newarray));
```

This assumes the length of both arrays are always equal.

https://jsfiddle.net/ddtybvo6/

Comment: Yes, the length of both arrays is always equal.

Comment: This solution is not easily scalable to more than two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) with the [zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) function:

```
var array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
var array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];

_.zip(array1, array2);
// [["one", "1"], ["two", "2"], ["three", "3"]]
```

> **zip**
>
> Merges together the values of each of the arrays
>   with the values at the corresponding position. Useful when you have
>   separate data sources that are coordinated through matching array
>   indexes. Use with apply to pass in an array of arrays. If you're
>   working with a matrix of nested arrays, this can be used to transpose
>   the matrix.
>
> ```
> _.zip(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50], [true, false, false]);
> => [["moe", 30, true], ["larry", 40, false], ["curly", 50, false]]
> ```