# Javascript: How to Combine & Filter Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

I have 3 strings that I need to convert into arrays, from there I want to filter and then combine them using javascript, I need to note that I'm using Zapier and their javascript library is a bit limited but this is what I have so far:

Strings:

```
var type  = 'bundle, simple, simple';
var name  = 'Product1, Product2, Product3';
var price = '1.99, 2.99, 3.99';
```

I need to figure out how to convert the above 3 strings above into the following array using javascript:

```
var itemArray = [
        {type:"bundle", info: {name: "Product1", price: "1.99"}},
        {type:"simple", info: {name: "Product2", price: "2.99"}},
        {type:"simple", info: {name: "Product3", price: "3.99"}}];
```

From there I'm looking to filter out the `bundle` product type and only pass along the `simple` product arrays, I'm doing that with the following:

```
// Using a for loop
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; ++i) {
    var item = itemArray[i];
    if (item.type == 'simple') filtered.push(item);
}

return {filtered}; //this returns just the 2 simple product type arrays
```

So my question is, how do I take those 3 strings that I began with and convert those into my `itemArray` format using javascript?

Comment: Are you sure you want `[simple, {product2, 2.99}]` or do you want `[simple, product2, 2.99]` and same for the other array?

Comment: @PhillipMartin that would probably work as well, ideally I want each product name and price underneath it's corresponding product type

Comment: Why three arrays? Use objects! i.e `[{type:bundle,name:prod1,price:1.99},{type:simple,name:prod2,price:2.99}]`

Comment: You can make use of `zip` here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function

Comment: @georg yes that zip functionality is terribly missing in JS.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've updated my question to be a lot more specific, and added the current code that I'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of `map` and `filter` to first combine the three arrays you have and then filter out arrays that match `item_type='bundle'`.

```js
var item_type  = ['bundle', 'simple', 'simple'],
    item_name  = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'],
    item_price = [1.99, 2.99, 3.99],
    res = item_type.map(function(v,i) {
        //combine arrays
        return [v, { [item_name[i]]: item_price[i] }]; 
    }).filter(function(o) {
        // only allow items where 'item_type' is not "bundle"
        return o[0] != "bundle";
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, 2, null));
```

Comment: Modified @Kind user's solution using filter instead of slice

Answer (score 1):

Yes... JS is missing an `Array.prototype.zip()` functionality. Let's invent it and solve accordingly.

```js
Array.prototype.zip = function(...a){
  return this.map((e,i) => [e].concat(a.map(sa => sa[i])));
};

var itemType  = ["bundle", "simple", "simple"],
    itemName  = ["product1", "product2", "product3"],
    itemPrice = [1.99,2.99,3.99],
    result    = itemType.zip(itemName,itemPrice)
                        .map(sa => [sa[0],{[sa[1]]:sa[2]}])
                        .filter(t => t[0] === "simple");
console.log(result);
```

PS: I have swapped the place of the last `.map()` and `.filter()` functions to fit your requirement but amending the question yielding changes in the previous answers are not encouraged in SO.

Answer (score 0):

First, combine them all into an array of objects via `map`, then `filter`, then `map` again into the representation you need. Something like:

```
item_type
    .map((type, index) => ({ 
       type, 
       index, 
       name: item_name[index], 
       price: item_price[index]
    }))
    .filter(el => el.type === 'simple')
    .map(el => [el.type, {name: el.name, price: el.price}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the columns, transpose the arrays and build the wanted inner arrays.

```js
var item_type = ['bundle', 'simple', 'simple'],
    item_name = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'],
    item_price = [1.99, 2.99, 3.99],
    result = [item_type, item_name, item_price]
        .map((a, _, aa) => a.filter((b, i) => aa[0][i] !== 'bundle'))
        .reduce((r, a, i) => (a.forEach((b, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || [], r[j][i] = b)), r), [])
        .map(a => ({ type: a[0], info: { name: a[1], price: a[2] } }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```