# Can I use array.prototype.reduce() to process two arrays at once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of same length and I would like to somehow process them both at once with the reduce method. Something like:

```
var arr1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arr2 = [5, 10, 4, 9, 5];
var productSum = arr1.reduce(function(sumOfProducts, item, secondArrayItem) {
    /* here I would like to multiply item from arr1 by the item from arr2 at the same index */
    return sumOfProducts + item * secondArrayItem;  
}, 0, arr2)
console.log(productSum);  // 131
```

An option would of course be to access the correct item from `arr2` using `currentIndex`, but that solution is ugly as I am accessing a variable outside of the scope of the function.

My specific use case is that I have an array with resources like `var resources = [2, 5, 4, 6, 2]` and I want to check if each item is higher than corresponding resource cost in another array like `var cost = [3, 1, 0, 0, 1]`.

Is there some nice solution to this using the `reduce()` function?

Comment: You'd typically do this by zipping the 2 lists together, then reduce the zipped list. Don't know how to idiomatically zip lists in JS though.

Comment: "*that solution is ugly as I am accessing a variable outside of the scope of the function.*" - I don't see what's ugly about that, we do this all the time when accessing globals or using closures. The important thing is just that the variable is constant. What really is ugly about this solution is a) it's not symmetric (accessing arr1 works different than accessing arr2) and b) we didn't ensure that the arrays have the same length, so we don't know whether `arr2[i]` accesses a valid index.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) you can first zip the two lists, and then reduce it and use destructuring to extract the array elements and pass them as arguments to the callback:

```js
const reduceTwo = (callback, initialValue, arr1, arr2) =>
  R.reduce((acc, [x, y]) => callback(acc, x, y), initialValue, R.zip(arr1, arr2));

const arr1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = [5, 10, 4, 9, 5];
console.log(reduceTwo((acc, x, y) => acc + x * y, 0, arr1, arr2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using a whole library just for zip function seems a bit redundant to me...

Comment: @BoltKey Why? If you use webpack with tree shaking to bundle your code, it doesn't have any negative performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way that I know to do this is to combine the 2 lists into a list of corresponding pairs ("zipping"), then reduce the combined lists:

```
var zipped = zip(arr1, arr2)

reduce((acc, [x, y]) => (Use x and y), 
              zipped)
```

For implementations of `zip`, see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

(Will verify syntax when I got off of transit)

Comment: Is this the way to go even for huge arrays? I don't want to create a whole new array when I just want to iterate over the values of both arrays at once.

Comment: @BoltKey If you want to work with huge arrays, you should forget `reduce` and use a simple for loop.

Comment: @BoltKey This is a much better approach when dealing with lazy structures, I'll admit. It will require 1 iteration to zip, then another to reduce, and creates an intermediate list, so no, this will not be performant unfortunately.

Comment: @BoltKey And I agree with Michal (sorry, I butchered that). By using a simple for-loop that loops using an index, you can index both lists at once easily. That entirely gets rid of the need for any intermediate lists and unnecessary iteration. Sometimes good-old imperative methods are the best.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows with pure JS;

```js
var arr1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    arr2 = [5, 10, 4, 9, 5],
  result = arr1.reduce((r,c,i) => (r.sum = r.sum ? r.sum + c * r[i] : c * r[i], r), arr2.slice()).sum;
console.log(result);
```

I `.slice()` `arr2` in order to not mutate it with a state variable yet you may still do without slicing if you will not apply a `for in` loop to `arr2` afterwards or such...