# Convert a bidimensional array to a 1D array alternating their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a bidimensional array like this:

```
let test2d = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["baz", "biz"]
]
```

If I want to convert this 2D array into 1D array (***not alternating their values***), I can do it on two ways:

*First way:*

```
let merged = test2d.reduce( (prev, next) => prev.concat(next) )
console.log(merged) // ["foo", "bar", "baz", "biz"]
```

*Second way:*

```
let arr1d = [].concat.apply([], test2d)
console.log(arr1d) // ["foo", "bar", "baz", "biz"]
```

---

**Question: How can I get a 1D array but with their values alternated?** I mean like this:

```
["foo", "baz", "bar", "biz"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an array for each index and concat the arrays at the end.

```js
var array = [["foo", "bar"], ["baz", "biz"]],
    result = [].concat(...array.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, []));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, if you don't mind can you elaborate `(r[i] = r[i] || []).push(v)`? I've followed your solution up until that line of code and lost

Comment: you could make two lines of code of it: `r[i] = r[i] || [];` and `r[i].push(v)`. the first line checks if `r[i]` is truthy, like an array and if not it takes an array as assingment. the second pushes the item to this array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `zip` function defined here: [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

```
let zip= rows => rows[0].map((_,c)=>rows.map(row=>row[c]))
```

So you can call:

```
let arr1d = [].concat.apply([], zip(test2d))
```

Here's the full code:

```js
let test2d = [ ["foo", "bar"], ["baz", "biz"] ]

let zip = rows => rows[0].map((_, c) => rows.map(row => row[c]))

let arr1d = [].concat.apply([], zip(test2d))

console.log(arr1d)
```

Comment: Very elegant this one! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regular for loop? This is efficient and easiest to read.

```
var arr1d = [];
for (let i = 0; i < test2d[0].length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < test2d.length; j++) {
        arr1d.push(test2d[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works too, even with more rows and columns. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This solution is easy to understand, it simply uses nested for-loops to get the desired output:

```
var data = [];  // This will be the new array
let test2d =    // This is your 2D array
[  
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["baz", "biz"]
]

// Here we use nested for-loops to add the items to data[] in the desired order
for(var i = 0; i < test2d.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < test2d[0].length; j++) {
        data.push(test2d[j][i]);
    }
}

console.log(data); // Print the output :)
```

The *data* array is now equal to: `[ "foo", "baz", "bar", "biz" ]`

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution only works with my `test2d` array, but if I add more rows and columns to my array, it does not works. Why? Because the trick is to start the loop with the columns (`test2d[0].length`) not with the rows (`test2d.length`). Look on the **patstuart**'s answer.