# Is it possible to iterate across nested arrays using for...of and/or for...in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, iteration

Let's say I have a "rectangular grid" made of nested arrays, like this:

```
let board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
];
```

I am trying to iterate **across its columns**, so the result will be like `'a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'd0', 'a1'... etc`.

Of course I can do it using good old for loop:

```
const iterateAcrossColumnsES5 = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
      console.log(board[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But I like to try make it more ES6 like terse and readable. I am trying to use *for.. of* and/or *for.. in* loops, but I got only as far as:

```
const iterateAcrossColumnsES6 = () => {
  for (let [i, item] of Object.entries(board)) {
    for(let row of board) {
      console.log(row[i])
    }
  }
}
```

But it is nor *terse*  nor *readable*, and it kinda works only in case that *board* is a 'square' (the parent array length is the same as its childrens), otherwise I got either too much or not enough iterations.

It is possible to do it? I haven't try to use `map()` or `forEach()`, I'm O.K. with them, but I am curious if I can use only `for..of` or `for..in`.

Comment: ES6 is not a replacement for ES5, if a standard for loop makes sense, use a standard for loop.

Comment: @Keith I agree, i am just curious if it's possible.

Comment: You're looking for the `zip` function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function), then `firstCol = zip(...grid)[0]`

Comment: If you just want to console log each entry, then -> `for (let i of board) { for (let j of i) console.log(j); }`

Comment: @Keith Yes, I use it to iterate over *rows* , but I need to iterate over *columns*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing built-in for that in js, but with two tiny helper functions you can write the loop in a quite elegant way:

```js
function *chain(its) {
    for (let it of its)
        yield *it
}

function zip(arrays) {
    return arrays[0].map((e, i) => arrays.map(a => a[i]))
}

//

let board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
]


console.log([...chain(board)].join(' '))


console.log([...chain(zip(board))].join(' '))
```

`chain` connects multiple iterable objects so that you can iterate them as one thing and `zip` takes an array of arrays and transposes it.

Comment: Seems very interesting. I have to confess I have no clue why `*it` is yielded as a generator, but I will take a look at Kyle Simpsons 'Async and performance' and hopefully find an answer there…

Comment: Is it possible to pass a callback (`console.log()` is enough) at the end of a column?

Comment: @HynekS: if you need to do something for each column, it might be easier to use zip without chain and iterate them separately, `for(col of zip(board)) { for(item of col)... `

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose the matrix and then iterate.

```js
const transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || []).concat(v));
let board = [['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']];

for (let a of board.reduce(transpose, [])) {
    for (let v of a) {
        console.log(v);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I was looking for (a unicorn?), but very interesting, inspiring and probably useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to create an array of `a0,b0....` and then further reduce it. Then use join with delimiter `,` to create the desired result

```js
let board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
];



var result = board.reduce((res, b) => res.map((elem, i) => elem + ',' + b[i])).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The goal is to iterate items, not to print a comma-separated array.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the board's [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), and than use array spread or `for...of` to get the items:

```js
const board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
];

board[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  const rows = board.length;
  const max = rows * board[0].length;
  let current = 0;
  return {
    next: () => ({
      value: this[current % rows][parseInt(current / rows)],
      done: current++ === max
    })
  };
};

console.log([...board]);

for(const item of board) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `for...in`:

```js
var board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
];

var result = [];

for (var i in board)
    for (var j in board[i])
        result[+j * board.length + +i] = board[i][j];
    
console.log(result);
```

It is not recommended to use `for...in` on arrays. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Using `for...of`:

```js
var board = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
  ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
  ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
  ['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
];

var result = [], i=0,j=0;

for (var arr of board) {
    for (var val of arr)
        result[j++ * board.length + i] = val;
    i++;j=0;
}

console.log(result);
```

In case the inner arrays are uneven in length, empty values will be present in the array. So need to filter those.

Answer (score 0):

This will only serve your purpose if you have a square board.

```js
let board = [
  ["a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"],
  ["b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"],
  ["c0", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
  ["d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
  ["e0", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"]
];


for (const i in board) {
  for (const j in board) {
    console.log(board[j][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems, legit, but I want to iterate over the whole board, and let's suppose I don't know its  dimensions.

Comment: @edit: Well, yes, but these are *rows*, I need *colums*.

Comment: @HynekS Oops. I'm a bit sleepy after lunch.

Comment: @edit: It is O.K. if the board is a 'square' (same length of parent and children), but it fails if it's not.