# I can't write to DIV all items in object

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a div list with pop-up. Each div will get data-target attribute from an object. I can return all items in object, but get only last item.

```
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>

const portolioItemInfos = [
    { dataTarget: "tempero-restaurante" }, 
    { dataTarget: "aksam-gunesi" }
]

const div = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-item");
for (let key of div) {
    for (let item of portolioItemInfos) {
        key.setAttribute("data-target", item.dataTarget);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Comment: `key.setAttribute` replace the value in the given attribute, not append

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are overwriting the `data-target` attribute each loop. Instead you need to append to the end of the `data-target` attribute by getting the current value and adding the new value to the end of it. You can do this like so:

```
let prev = key.getAttribute('data-target');
prev = prev ? prev : '';
key.setAttribute("data-target", (prev +' ' +item.dataTarget).trim());
```

See example below (inspect element to see result):

```js
const portolioItemInfos = [{
    dataTarget: "tempero-restaurante"
  },
  {
    dataTarget: "aksam-gunesi"
  }
]

const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-item");
for (let key of divs) {
  for (let item of portolioItemInfos) {
    let prev = key.getAttribute('data-target');
    prev = prev ? prev : ''; // if prev is isn't null, set prev equal to prev. If prev is null, then set prev to the empty string
    
    key.setAttribute("data-target", (prev +' ' +item.dataTarget).trim());
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each `div` you loop over all your `portolioItemInfos` so each `div` take the last value of the loop.

You can actually simplify it and don't need to loop over the `portolioItemInfos`, just use the index of a `for` loop to assign the right `dataTarget`.

```js
const portolioItemInfos = [
  {
    dataTarget: 'tempero-restaurante'
  },
  {
    dataTarget: 'aksam-gunesi'
  }
];

const div = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item');
for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
   div[i].setAttribute('data-target', portolioItemInfos[i].dataTarget);
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` approach instead traditional `for` loop, like following:

```js
const portolioItemInfos = [
 { dataTarget: "tempero-restaurante" }, 
 { dataTarget: "aksam-gunesi" }
]

const div = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-item");

portolioItemInfos.forEach(function(item, index){
 div[index].setAttribute("data-target", portolioItemInfos[index].dataTarget);
})
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
<div class="portfolio-item" data-toggle="modal"></div>
```

You can also iterate over DOM element object array as well:

```
div.forEach(function(item, index){
    div[index].setAttribute("data-target", portolioItemInfos[index].dataTarget);
})
```