# How to loop through sub arrays of a parent array but iterate over one index per sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How does one loop through sub arrays of a parent array but iterate over one index per sub array.

I know the solution I want involves at least iterating over a 2D array but I currently know how to print all elements of sub arrays in a parent array

For example say I have `const array = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['@', '#', '%']];`

How do I get `const result = [[1, 'a', '@'], [2, 'b', '#'], [3, 'c', '%'];` ?

Comment: This operation is called [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)), and to search for the right answer you should search for "javascript zip array",  which would bring you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717/8557739).

Comment: `array[0].map((_, i) => array.map(row => row[i]))`

Comment: Wow! thanks, sorry for asking a duplicate question, I did not know there was an actual word for what I was describing ie transposing sub arrays in an array. I think I have enough clues and answers to play with and understand. Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i got, See if you like it.

```js
const array = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['@', '#', '%']];
var res =array.map((a,i)=>{ 
return a.map((x, index)=>{
  return array[index][i]
 });
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This only works for square matrix (2D array with same number of rows and columns). It won't work for `[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Comment: Well is it not what he needs? he marked it as an answer so.