# How to convert array of object to desired object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert array of object to a desired format in javascript, Please help me to resolve this.

```
const obj = [
  {name: 'parry1', age:22, height:5},
  {name: 'parry 2', age:23, height:6},
  {name: 'parry3', age:24, height:7}
]

// output = {name:['parry1', 'parry 2', 'parry3'], age:[22, 23, 24], height:[5, 6, 7]}
```

Comment: Ok, we can help, but, where is the code you are using to try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map your array to the entries of your object (using `.map`), and then use `.forEach` with `.reduce()` to build an object which has each key from your objects in your array with the values being arrays populated with their respective value:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'parry1', age:22, height:5}, {name: 'parry 2', age:23, height:6}, {name: 'parry3', age:24, height:7}];

const res = arr.map(Object.entries).reduce((acc, entries) => {
  entries.forEach(([k, v]) => {
    acc[k] = [...(acc[k] || []), v];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you !

```js
const obj = [
  {name: 'parry1', age:22, height:5},
  {name: 'parry 2', age:23, height:6},
  {name: 'parry3', age:24, height:7}
];

function ArrayToObject(array){
  const newObj={
    name: [],
    age: [],
    height: []
  };
  array.forEach(function(row){
    newObj.name.push(row["name"]);
    newObj.age.push(row["age"]);
    newObj.height.push(row["height"]);
  });
  return newObj;
}

console.log( ArrayToObject(obj) );
```

```html
output = {name:['parry1', 'parry 2', 'parry3'], age:[22, 23, 24], height:[5, 6, 7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for the [`zip` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function):

```js
let zip = (...a) => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(b => b[i]))

const obj = [
    {name: 'parry1', age: 22, height: 5},
    {name: 'parry 2', age: 23, height: 6},
    {name: 'parry3', age: 24, height: 7}
]

res = Object.fromEntries(
    zip(
        Object.keys(obj[0]),
        zip(...obj.map(Object.values))
    ));


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries and return an object with all keys as arrays with their values.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'parry1', age: 22, height: 5 }, { name: 'parry 2', age: 23, height: 6 }, { name: 'parry3', age: 24, height: 7 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => Object.entries(o).reduce((q, [k, v]) => {
        q[k] = q[k] || [];
        q[k].push(v);
        return q;
    }, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const obj = [
  {name: 'parry1', age:22, height:5},
  {name: 'parry 2', age:23, height:6},
  {name: 'parry3', age:24, height:7}
]

let output = {};

obj.forEach((o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach((prop) => {
    if (output[prop] === undefined) {
      output[prop] = [];
    }

    output[prop].push(o[prop]);
  });
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the original array. For each row, check if there is a corresponding field in the resObj. If no, then create the field. Push the value into this field.

Code -

```
const obj = [
  {name: 'parry1', age:22, height:5},
  {name: 'parry 2', age:23, height:6},
  {name: 'parry3', age:24, height:7}
]

function arrayToObj(arr) {
  let resObj={};
  arr.forEach(row=> {
    Object.keys(row).forEach(key=>{
      if(!resObj[key]) {
        resObj[key]=[];
      }
      resObj[key].push(row[key]);
    })
  })
  return resObj;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayToObj(obj)));
// {"name":["parry1","parry 2","parry3"],"age":[22,23,24],"height":[5,6,7]}
```