# How can i merge two arrays in one array of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two arrays:

```
const firstArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const secondArr = ['somevalue', 'anothervalue', 'another', 'other']
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
const final = [[1, 'somevalue'], [2, 'anothervalue'], [3, 'another'], [4, 'other']]
```

Where each value of the two arrays is associated with another value and put into an array. So for example, the first value of `firstArr` should be associated with the first value of `secondArr` in a sub-array on the `final` array.

Is there some function in Javascript to do this or am i going to have to do it another way, for example with a loop?

Comment: This is called "zipping" arrays/lists/etc together, and once you know that, you can pretty much immediately find the answer. For the "duplicate" flag, there are a _lot_ of answers, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/740553 is the one you want to look at: it's literally a one-liner in modern JS.

Comment: Indeed, looking for the JS equivalent of zipping is helping me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to a single array

```js
const firstArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const secondArr = ['somevalue', 'anothervalue', 'another', 'other'];
const final = firstArr.reduce((arr, val, i) => (arr.push([val, secondArr[i]]), arr), []);

console.log(final)
```

Or the old-school way if you like it to be less cryptic:

```js
const firstArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const secondArr = ['somevalue', 'anothervalue', 'another', 'other'];
const final = [];

for (let i=0; i<firstArr.length; i++) {
  final.push([firstArr[i], secondArr[i]]);
}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```js
const firstArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const secondArr = ['somevalue', 'anothervalue', 'another', 'other']
let finalArr = [];

firstArr.forEach((elm, i) => {
  finalArr[i] = [elm, secondArr[i]];
});
console.log(finalArr);
```