# How to create array of objects from two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to merge two arrays into one array of objects,
ie:
I have two arrays:

```
dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2020-02-01'];
values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8];
```

and I want to assign to another variable this:

```
someData = [['2020-01-01', 0.1], ['2020-01-15', 0.4], ['2020-02-01', 0.8]];
```

edit:
I'm courios if there is any more elegant solution than this:

```
const someData;
this.dates.forEach((value, i )=>{
  someData.push([dates[i]],value);
})
```

Comment: Show your current code?

Comment: @Mehdi - I updated answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2020-02-01'];
const values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8];

const result = dates.map((x,i) => new Array(x, values[i]));
console.log(result);
```

Using a map to iterate through the dates and return a new array along with values in it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2020-02-01'];
const values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8];
const newArray = dates.map((item,index) => [item,values[index]]);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an elegant solution, take inspiration from Haskell's `zip`.

```
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map((k, i) => [k, arr2[i]]);
}

const someData = zip(dates, values).
```

Answer (score 0):

you are really just creating an array of arrays.  Consider:

```js
var dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', '2020-02-01'];
    var values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8];
    var theArray=[];
    for(let i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
        var littleArray=[];
        littleArray.push(dates[i],values[i]);        
        theArray.push(littleArray);
     }

    console.log(theArray);
```