# Lopping List with in List (many to many) using map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

How to loop list with another list .The number of counts are same inside each list

```
List1 =[a,b,c,d]
List2 =[e,f,g,h]
```

Output

```
a 
 e
b
 f
c
 g
d
 h
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Comment: why not for loop?

Comment: Anything is fine for me with react code which should have expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary for this

const list = { a: ['e'], b: ['f'], c: ['g'], d: ['h'] };

and then do this in react.

```
    Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
    return list[key].map((val) => {
        return `${key} \n ${val}`;
    })
    .join('\n');
    })
    .join('\n');
```

Updated*: As you've asked to you would create this dictionary considering that both the list will be of same length and no duplicates, this is how I would do it.

```
    const l1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
    const l2 = ['e','f','g','h'];
    let l3 = {};
    l1.forEach((v, i) => {
        l3[v] = l2[i]; 
    });
```

Comment: How to create a dictionary for this... Is this achievable in react?

Comment: This is not something which is react related but done through javascript. I will update in the answer.