# Javascript - How to combine seperate individual array to single array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 2 individual arrays that consists of lat and long values respectively.

```
lat = [23,34,25];
long = [11,12,13];
```

My question is how do i create output of combined lat and long arrays above to :

```
combined_latlong = [ [23,11] , [32,12], [25,13] ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const lat = [23, 34, 25];
const long = [11, 12, 13];

const result = lat.map((l, i) => [l, long[i]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works like a charm for my application. God bless you.