# Systematacally combining arrays

Tags: javascript

so i have these three arrays:

```
  var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
  var b = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var c = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

i want to combine them like so:

```
  var d = [
    ["one", "a", "1"],
    ["two", "b", "2"],
    ["three", "c", "3"],
  ];
```

how do i do this? I know i need a foor loop but i cant seem to understand how to set it up. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Yeah, this example is on a smaller scale. The data is much more abstract than so. but i think that what you did would work using a loop

Comment: The operation you want to perform is called `zip`.

Comment: @Nick `var d = [a, b, c]` would be the transposed version of what OP wants.

Comment: oh, yep, I missed that

Comment: Another useful dupe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like:

```js
const a = ['one', 'two', 'three'], b = ['a', 'b', 'c'], c = ['1', '2', '3'], combo = [];
for(let i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
  combo.push([a[i], b[i], c[i]]);
}
console.log(combo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the arrays are the same length:

First combine them into one array:

```js
let combined = [a, b, c];
```

Then iterate through them all at the same time:

```js
var d = [];

for (var i = 0; i < combined[0].length; i ++) {
    d.push(combined.map(arr => arr[i]));
}
```