# Better mapping from two different objects with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am able to achieve my goal, I split `list` to be `[0]` and `[1]`, I am thinking maybe there is a better solution with es6? Thanks

```js
const list = [
  [
      { value: 'Apple' },
      { value: 'Banana'},
      { value: 'Orange'},
      { value: 'Grape' },
  ],
  [
      {value: 'color is Red' },
      {value: 'color is Yellow'},
      {value: 'color is Orange'},
      {value: 'color is green'},
  ]]


const a = list[0];
const b = list[1];


const c = a.map(({value}, index)=>{
  return {[value] : b[index].value};
})

console.log(c)
```

result to expect is

```
[
  {
    "Apple": "color is Red"
  },
  {
    "Banana": "color is Yellow"
  },
  {
    "Orange": "color is Orange"
  },
  {
    "Grape": "color is green"
  }
]
```

Comment: `const [a, b] = list;` but I'm not sure it's THAT much better. Unless you mean the next operation, in which case check [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717)

Comment: Can you change the input format? It's weird to have a list of exactly two elements.

Comment: Thanks, no, I can't change the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Array destructuring.

```
const [first, second] = list;
first.map(({value}, index) => {
  return {[value] : second[index].value};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [
  [
    { value: "Apple" },
    { value: "Banana" },
    { value: "Orange" },
    { value: "Grape" },
  ],
  [
    { value: "color is Red" },
    { value: "color is Yellow" },
    { value: "color is Orange" },
    { value: "color is green" },
  ],
];

const [fruit, prop] = list;
const result = fruit.map(({ value }, i) => ({ [value]: prop[i].value }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry, that wasn't me.