# How to arrange an unlabeled array into a labelled array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, algorithmic-trading, ta-lib

I am making a trading bot for Indian Stock market.
I have stock data in this form

```
data = [[ 1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806 ], [ 1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388 ], [ 1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338 ],...........]
```

which is represented according to order as

```
[[time stamp, Open Price, High Price, Low Price, Close Price, Volume], [.....]]
```

I want to arrange it in labelled array as

```
{ open: [...], close: [...], high: [...], low: [...], volume: [...] }
```

I am using TALIB Library which uses data in this form to use indicator.

**I have seen this to be done using Python and pandas but need solution in javascript.**

Thanks

Comment: Just to say that a _"labelled array"_ is an object in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the data manipulation.

```js
const data = [[ 1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806 ], [ 1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388 ], [ 1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338 ]];
const open = [], close = [], high = [], low = [], volume = [];

data.forEach(elm => {
    open.push(elm[1])
    high.push(elm[2])
    low.push(elm[3])
    close.push(elm[4])
    volume.push(elm[5])
});

const result = {open, high, low, close, volume};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  [1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806],
  [1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388],
  [1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338]
]
const result = {
  open: [],
  high: [],
  low: [],
  close: [],
  volume: []
}
data.forEach(item => {
  result.open.push(item[1])
  result.high.push(item[2])
  result.low.push(item[3])
  result.close.push(item[4])
  result.volume.push(item[5])
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) function to zip your nested arrays by index and pass the result to a constructor for your expected data shape.

```js
const zip = (...r) => [...r[0]].map((_, c) => r.map(s => s[c]));

const Data = ([_timestamp, open, close, high, low, volume]) => ({ open, close, high, low, volume });

// usage
const data = [[1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806], [1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388], [1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338]];

const result = Data(zip(...data));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily built atop some reusable helper functions.  `transpose` flips a matrix so that the columns turn into rows.  `zipObj` takes an array of keys and and array of values and produces an object with the corresponding values associated with each key.  With those, we can write this almost trivially:

```js
const transpose = (xs) => 
  xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))
  
const zipObj = (keys) => (vals) => 
  Object .fromEntries (transpose ([keys, vals]))

const restructure = (data) => 
  zipObj (['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']) (transpose (data))

const data = [[1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806], [1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388], [1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338]];

console .log (restructure (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This includes the `timestamp` values.  If you don't want them, then we can remove each with another helper (`tail` just returns an array without its first value) and then simply not include `timestamp` in the list of keys.  You can see this by expanding the following snippet:

```js
const tail  = (xs) => xs .slice (1)

const transpose = (xs) => 
  xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))
  
const zipObj = (keys) => (vals) => 
  Object .fromEntries (transpose ([keys, vals]))

const restructure = (data) => 
  zipObj (['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']) (transpose (data .map (tail)))

const data = [[1627875900, 434.75, 435.8, 432.55, 434.9, 1750806], [1627876800, 434.75, 435.2, 432.7, 433, 905388], [1627877700, 432.9, 433.75, 431.8, 433.55, 689338]];

console .log (restructure (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```