# matrix (array of arrays|bidimensional array) sum without loops. There are a better way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I was thinking on a way to make matrix sum without have to use loops and I realize use Array.prototype.map() is a good way.

```js
var multArray = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];
var multArray2=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];
total   =  multArray.map((array, arrayIndex) => array.map((value, index) => value + multArray2[arrayIndex][index]));
console.log(total);
```

Do you know if there are a better or short way?

Thanks!.

Comment: What is bad about loops, when they would be a much cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is subjective, but you can do something like this:

```js
var multArray = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];
var multArray2=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];
console.log(
  [...Array(multArray.length).keys()].map(
     f => [...Array(multArray[f].length).keys()].map(
        s => multArray[f][s] + multArray2[f][s]
     )
  )
)
```

But IMO your one is more readable

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `for` loop is the most explicit in terms of clearly showing what is happening.

```js
const multArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];
const multArray2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];

const total = [];

for (let i = 0; i < multArray.length; i++) {
  total[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < multArray[i].length; j++) {
    total[i][j] = multArray[i][j] + multArray2[i][j];
  }
}

console.log(total);
```

But if you really don't want to you could define some utility functions and chain them.

```js
const multArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];
const multArray2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];

const zip = (a, b) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]]);
const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const total = zip(multArray, multArray2).map((c) => zip(...c).map(sum));

console.log(total);
```

A real advantage can be gained by redefining the `zip()` function to accept any number of parameters and thus allowing you to total any number of arrays by simply passing them all to the initial `zip` call (and avoiding explicitly writing nested loops for each additional array).

```js
const multArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];
const multArray2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];
const multArray3 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],];

const zip = (...rows) => [...rows[0].keys()].map((k) => rows.map((row) => row[k]));
const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const sum_mult_arrays = (...arrs) => zip(...arrs).map((c) => zip(...c).map(sum));

const total = sum_mult_arrays(multArray, multArray2, multArray3);

console.log(total);
```

See [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) for a lot of discussion around zipping.