# Javascript Array String Generator Problem

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

My web page allows users to generate strings/phrases by selecting a combination of two radio buttons from two different groups: mode and category. After selecting their choice of buttons, they click the 'Push' button and a string pops up. See the snippet below:

```js
class modes {
    constructor(items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.randomUnused = [...items];
        this.forwardIndex = 0;
        this.reverseIndex = items.length - 1;
    }
    forwardItem() {
        return this.items[this.forwardIndex++ % (this.items.length)];
    }
    randomItem() {
        if (!this.randomUnused.length) {
          this.randomUnused.push(...this.items);
        }
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.randomUnused.length);
        return this.randomUnused.splice(index, 1);
    }
    reverseItem() {
        if (this.reverseIndex < 0) {
          this.reverseIndex = this.items.length - 1;
        }
        return this.items[this.reverseIndex--];
    }
}
const categ = {
    A: new modes([
        "A example 1",
        "A example 2",
        "A example 3",
        "A example 4",
    ]),
    B: new modes([
        "B example 1",
        "B example 2",
        "B example 3",
        "B example 4",
    ]),
    C: new modes([
        "C example 1",
        "C example 2",
        "C example 3",
        "C example 4",
    ]),
    D: new modes([
        "D example 1",
        "D example 2",
        "D example 3",
        "D example 4",
    ])
};
function main() {
    const output = document.querySelector("output");
    if(!(document.forms.thingSelection2.type.value in categ)) {
        return false;
    }
    const list = categ[document.forms.thingSelection2.type.value];
    const method = document.forms.thingSelection1.mode.value + "Item";
    const item = list[method]();
    output.innerHTML = item;
}
const abutton = document.getElementById("abutton");
if(abutton) {
    abutton.addEventListener("click", main);
}
```

```html
<output></output>

<button id="abutton">Push</button>

<form name="thingSelection1">
    Forwards<input type="radio" name="mode" value="forward">
    Random<input type="radio" name="mode" value="random">
    Backwards<input type="radio" name="mode" value="reverse">
</form>

<form name="thingSelection2">
    <li><input type="radio" name="type" value="A">Choice A</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="type" value="B">Choice B</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="type" value="C">Choice C</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="type" value="D">Choice D</li>
</form>
```

Each category is currently represented by a radio button and has its own separate array, so only one may be selected at a time. My goal is to allow the user to select multiple categories and combine them into a new array, then cycle through them.

Problem 1: Changing the category radio buttons into checkboxes causes the function to break. The snippet below illustrates this. I figure this is due to the fact that checkboxes have 3 possible states (checked, unchecked, indeterminate) while radio buttons can only be true or false. I am unsure what changes to make to the function to allow the checkboxes to work. I could use some assistance. I'm fairly new to javascript, so please be patient.

```js
class modes {
    constructor(items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.randomUnused = [...items];
        this.forwardIndex = 0;
        this.reverseIndex = items.length - 1;
    }
    forwardItem() {
        return this.items[this.forwardIndex++ % (this.items.length)];
    }
    randomItem() {
        if (!this.randomUnused.length) {
          this.randomUnused.push(...this.items);
        }
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.randomUnused.length);
        return this.randomUnused.splice(index, 1);
    }
    reverseItem() {
        if (this.reverseIndex < 0) {
          this.reverseIndex = this.items.length - 1;
        }
        return this.items[this.reverseIndex--];
    }
}
const categ = {
    A: new modes([
        "A example 1",
        "A example 2",
        "A example 3",
        "A example 4",
    ]),
    B: new modes([
        "B example 1",
        "B example 2",
        "B example 3",
        "B example 4",
    ]),
    C: new modes([
        "C example 1",
        "C example 2",
        "C example 3",
        "C example 4",
    ]),
    D: new modes([
        "D example 1",
        "D example 2",
        "D example 3",
        "D example 4",
    ])
};
function main() {
    const output = document.querySelector("output");
    if(!(document.forms.thingSelection2.type.value in categ)) {
        return false;
    }
    const list = categ[document.forms.thingSelection2.type.value];
    const method = document.forms.thingSelection1.mode.value + "Item";
    const item = list[method]();
    output.innerHTML = item;
}
const abutton = document.getElementById("abutton");
if(abutton) {
    abutton.addEventListener("click", main);
}
```

```html
<output></output>

<button id="abutton">Push</button>

<form name="thingSelection1">
    Forwards<input type="radio" name="mode" value="forward">
    Random<input type="radio" name="mode" value="random">
    Backwards<input type="radio" name="mode" value="reverse">
</form>

<form name="thingSelection2">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="A">Choice A</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="B">Choice B</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="C">Choice C</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="D">Choice D</li>
</form>
```

Problem 2: Constructing the custom array in a specific order. While internet searches provide many ways to combine multiple arrays into one, like concat, none of them explain how to organize the strings in a custom order.

Example of what im looking for: `["A example 1", "B example 1", "C example 1", "D example 1", "A example 2", "B example 2"...]`

Rather than simply stacking the array contents on top of each other, like concat and every other method of combining arrays: `["A example 1", "A example 2", "A example 3", "A example 4", "B example 1", "B example 2"...]`

I'm unaware of any method to achieve this. No external libraries please.

Comment: The ordered concatenation you're describing is often referred to as `zipping` see: [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) for discussion

Comment: As for problem 1, unlike radio buttons which will only return a single value for a given group, checkboxes can be checked or unchecked without regard for other like named checkboxes. To solve it you'll need to iterate over each checkbox, see if it's checked and retreive the relevant list. (or use `onChange` and keep track of which are checked)

Comment: @pilchard Any chance you could show me in a snippet? I'm new and eager to learn, but I'm unsure of how to approach that.