# Combine map() and concat() JavaScript - cleaner code question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to combine map() and concat() in the following code to make it cleaner/shorter?

```
const firstColumnData = data.map((item: any) => {
 return item.firstColumn;
});

const secondColumnData = data.map((item: any) => {
 return item.secondColumn;
});

const allData = firstColumnData.concat(secondColumnData);
```

For context, later in the file allData is mapped through to populate data into columns. The specific data depends on which page is calling the component.

Basically, I am wondering if I can skip the declaration of firstColumnData and secondColumn data and assign the value to allData directly. This is an example of how I tried to refactor, but it did not work. (white page, could not render)

```
const allData = data.map((item: any => { 
return item.firstColumn.concat(item.secondColumn)
});
```

Comment: You can do `data.flatMap(item => [item.firstColumn, item.secondColumn])`, but that of course changes order

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single `reduce()` operation. Arguably, what you save by only having to iterate once, you lose in readability:

```js
const data =[
  {firstColumn: 1, secondColumn: 2},
  {firstColumn: 3, secondColumn: 4}
];

const result = data.reduce((a, {firstColumn, secondColumn}, i, {length}) => {
  a[i] = firstColumn;
  a[i + length] = secondColumn;
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That answers my question, thank you! I agree that this is more difficult to read than the original but I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robby that readability is probably the most important part in this.

You could one line this though, as:

`const allData = [...data.map(item => item.firstColumn), ...data.map(item.secondColumn)];`

but in this case you're still looping twice, so you haven't saved any computation, you've just made it shorter to write.

Comment: I never said readability is the most important part. If you have to do this for a 10,000 element array on every clock tick, readability goes out the window in favor of performance. Additionally, the reduce operation would scale to more than 2 properties, while still maintaining one iteration.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Apologies, I should have said "I agree with Robby in that you're potentially losing readability if you move this to a reduce function"

Comment: No apologies needed at all. Was just clarifying my stance :)

Answer (score 0):

##### Looping your current logic

My original answer below is, of course, performant as the proverbial January molasses even though I like the shape of it.

A little testing shows that just putting your current logic into a loop offers about the same or better performance than a generalized version RobbyCornelissen's answer (unless you unroll the loop in the reduce...) and has the benefit of simplicity. It relies on defining an array of column properties to iterate over.

```js
const
  data = [{ firstColumn: 1, secondColumn: 2 }, { firstColumn: 3, secondColumn: 4 }],
  columns = ['firstColumn', 'secondColumn'],
  result = [].concat(...columns.map(col => data.map((item) => item[col])));

console.log(result);
```

###### Generalized reduce()

```js
const
  data = [{ firstColumn: 1, secondColumn: 2 }, { firstColumn: 3, secondColumn: 4 }],
  columns = ['firstColumn', 'secondColumn'],
  result = data.reduce((a, item, i, { length }) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
      a[i + length * j] = item[columns[j]]
    }
    return a
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

##### Zip (original answer)

If the properties are guaranteed to be in order you could 'zip' the `Object.values`. This will handle any number of properties without explicit desctructuring.

```js
const data = [
  { firstColumn: 1, secondColumn: 2 },
  { firstColumn: 3, secondColumn: 4 }
];

const result = zip(...data.map(Object.values)).flat()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/13762301
 */
 const zip = (...rows) => [...rows[0]].map((_, c) => rows.map((row) => row[c]));
</script>
```

But to avoid relying on property order you can still destructure.

```
const result = zip(...data.map(({ firstColumn, secondColumn }) => [firstColumn, secondColumn])).flat()
```

see: [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) for more discussion on 'zip'.