# Sort 2D Array in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a array like this:

```
const arr = [['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Bird'],[1, 4, 2, 3]];
```

How would I sort it so its in the order:

```
const arr = [['Dog', 'Fish', 'Bird', 'Cat'],[1, 2, 3, 4]];
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

[`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) them, sort, and `zip` again:

```js
let zip = args => args[0].map((_, i) => args.map(a => a[i]))

//

const arr = [['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Bird'],[1, 4, 2, 3]];

r = zip(zip(arr).sort((x, y) => x[1] - y[1]))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over `items` while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the key is the item and the value is its initial index
- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get), sort the items according to the index  map above
- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort the indices array

```js
const sort = ([ items, indices ]) => {
  const indexMap = items.reduce((map, item, index) => 
    map.set(item, indices[index])
  , new Map);
  return [
    items.sort((a, b) => indexMap.get(a) - indexMap.get(b)),
    indices.sort()
  ];
}


console.log( sort([['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Bird'], [1, 4, 2, 3]]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your index array has all numbers from 1 to n:

```
function deepSort(arr2d) {
  const [stringArr, indexArr] = arr2d
  const result = []
  indexArr.forEach((index, i) => result[index - 1] = stringArr[i])
  return [result, indexArr.sort()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort an array of indices amnd map the values according to the indices array.

```js
const
    array = [['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Bird'], [1, 4, 2, 3]],
    indices = [...array[1].keys()].sort((a, b) => array[1][a] - array[1][b]);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = indices.map(j => array[i][j]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```