# How do connectively sort 2 arrays in a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this 2d Array in JavaScript:

```
['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent']
['0', '3', '0', '4']
```

in which the numbers stand for the amount of guesses the user took to guess a random number.
and i want it to look like this:

```
['Jonas', 'Vincent', 'Simon', 'Daniela']
['3', '4', '0', '0']
```

so basically, sorted by the numbers from lowest to highest (except 0 since the user didnt finish his run), but the names sorted accordingly to the numbers.

How (if) is this possible?

I tried sorting it like normally like a 2d Array and it didnt work, i tried splitting the different array and sorting them manually but then i dont know how to sort them connectively.

Comment: A 2D array would be: `[['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent'],
['0', '3', '0', '4']]` - not what you're presenting. But I assume that's what is meant there. Can you should the code of your best attempt? Also, why don't you use a better data model for your task?: `[{name: "foo", score: 4}, {...]`

Comment: You need to connect the two, either join them into tuples or objects, or create a Map indexed by user name with guesses as value. Storing them separately is only going to lead to headaches and possible data dissociation over time.

Comment: some considerations: why not take a single array with objects or at least arrays of name and count? and why not take for count a number instead of a string with a numerical value? ususally it is better to treat numbers as numbers and avoid to convert this value to string and to number and again to string.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to keep arrays, you could take an array of indices, sort by the values and map finally both arrays with the indices.

```js
let names = ['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent'],
    values = ['0', '3', '0', '4'],
    indices = [...values.keys()].sort((a, b) =>
        (+values[a] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (+values[b] || Number.MAX_VALUE)
    );

[names, values] = [names, values].map(a => indices.map(i => a[i]));

console.log(...names);
console.log(...values);
```

Comment: @Thatkookooguy that is the OP's expected output, read the full question. *'`['3', '4', '0', '0']` ...so basically, sorted by the numbers from lowest to highest (except 0 since the user didnt finish his run)'*

Answer (score 0):

Map the original array into pairs like `[['0', 'Daniela'], ...]`. Then sort by the number, treating zero as a special case that will always be last in the sort. Then use reduce to map the pairs back into the original 2D array format.

```js
const arr = [['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent'],
             ['0', '3', '0', '4']]

console.log(arr[0].map((e,i)=>[arr[1][i],e])
  .sort(([a],[b])=>((a==0)-(b==0) || a-b))
  .reduce((a,[x,y])=>(a[0].push(y),a[1].push(x),a),[[],[]]))
```

Comment: spacesmakestuffeasiertoread ;)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Roko, an array of objects is preferred in this particular situation as it helps making a sorting function much easier.

However, if that is not at all possible we can zip them manually:

```js
const zipped = users.map(
  (user, index) => ({ name: user, guesses: Number(guesses[index]) })
);
```

Then, we sort them based on their guesses. Note how I use [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) as the sorting value if `user.guesses === 0`.

```js
zipped.sort(
  (user1, user2) => (user1.guesses || Infinity) - (user2.guesses || Infinity)
);
```

However, how the order of users who did not complete the test was not specified. Hence, their order are assumed to be preserved.

Try it (I separated `zipped` back to two arrays, just in case you need them):

```js
const users = ['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent'];
const guesses = ['0', '3', '0', '4'];

const zipped = users.map(
  (user, index) => ({ name: user, guesses: Number(guesses[index]) })
);

zipped.sort(
  (user1, user2) => (user1.guesses || Infinity) - (user2.guesses || Infinity)
);

console.log(zipped);

const [sortedUsers, sortedGuesses] = zipped.reduce(
  ([sortedUsers, sortedGuesses], currentUser) => [
    [...sortedUsers, currentUser.name],
    [...sortedGuesses, currentUser.guesses],
  ], [[], []]
);

console.log(sortedUsers, sortedGuesses);
```

Comment: This is a good explanation, but your reduce is highly inefficient since it repeatedly destructures, creates a new array, and then spreads. Just push to the initial accumulators.

Comment: `[newUsers.push(user.name) && newUsers, newGuesses.push(user.guesses) && newGuesses]` looks way more complicated than the way I chose. If the data is not too large difference in performance should be negligible.

Comment: Don't destructure either, just push and return. `zipped.reduce((acc, currentUser) => { acc[0].push(user.name); acc[1].push(user.guesses); return acc; }, [[],[]]);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for the [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) function:

```js
let zip = (...a) => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(r => r[i]))

//

let names = ['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent']
let scores = [0, 3, 0, 4]

let temp = zip(scores, names);
temp.sort((x, y) => (x[0] || Infinity) - (y[0] || Infinity));
[scores, names] = zip(...temp);

console.log(...names)
console.log(...scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient sorting method, without creating new arrays and objects.
Minimum runtime.

```js
const names = ['Daniela', 'Jonas', 'Simon', 'Vincent'];
const numbers = ['0', '3', '0', '4'];
for (let i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1] && +numbers[j + 1] || !+numbers[j]) {
            [names[j], names[j + 1]] = [names[j + 1], names[j]];
            [numbers[j], numbers[j + 1]] = [numbers[j + 1], numbers[j]];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(...names);
```