# Javascript Array - customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I have the data like the below from API.I want to format the data. can anyone will help?

```
  fields: [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: {
        data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
      }
    }
  ]
```

how to get the output like this

```
var d = [ [1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10] ]
```

Comment: That's definitely not a valid array. `[{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}]` [isn't valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAd2.png) in JavaScript. It throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

Comment: sorry my mistake.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to show us your attempts.

Comment: @RAJA I tried giving an initial solution based on what you have given and what I assumed. Tell me if there are any other dynamic parts to be considered?

Comment: Python has a native feature that can 'zip' lists. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function) are some JavaScript implementations of zip.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks, learnt something new. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of fields is dynamic instead of just two: you can iterate over the length of the first field's array in an outer loop, then iterate over each field in an inner loop to pick out the number within that field's array at the index from the outer loop (after first verifying that the length of each number array is the same for every field):

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZwA50wUwAoAoRRYGfAGwBNMAuRAJXzRoSoE8BBFdTgDwBvRADc0VEPgaIRNNFDSMWbDjz5pBYEAFsARvhQA+RAF8zRgDTEAlI237DAbQC6r2aUQQEmKIir4YADmUAAWiAC85JS0mE4ADC4A-AB04pLSKfKKKQHBYQDcnjDAiIRQnNj4cKV5IeEAhBFRAEQOBigtNogo+FAgKEiuRcWlhBTUdCmYcDpE4zE03REmE7RpElKYWQpouYH1iE1RdWE23UKeZGEocADuiGD4DwCifHAohC0AkpA+ML5An5TqFMF0imRTMRPN4sH5epgQFQoPZdB1XO4osNoWRgB8ygE-DBIoh4gVEMSBP4DoUKYgANRRACMFyuXh8fnahhkXJQmMQ2LIuPxhFhvmik0QNQlsVZQqFvO22BAmFCC0mGwy22yaCcMBcDRsEKFUPlCKRUBSytVhEVRs8UM8vX6gx60gtRUdYr8azoJKcnku8rAaDmjBa3Ba1nl6S2jCD8sQOsYTiZlkQACZ0wBmdMAFnTAFYXNGTaXTKWE2QQ2HEC0AEJRtmx6TxtlkZMCgBs6YA7OmABzpgCc6aZiVLkPL1hcI29iHwAA8qtB8DR-an012SwKs4hezunLnEAPDwXEMPD4Wx4lZ9D52hoCAJCTUBgcHgiL7MPbiGK4AEuRwEEhCPv0Ej2v+gFUMBhAAFIAMoAPIAHLTKgMDBCUnCgU+EGRM0iCIah6EoJhQTYYQS4rlAa7nEUQA)

```js
function transpose(fields) {
  const length = fields[0]?.values.data.length;
  if (typeof length !== "number") return [];

  if (fields.some((field) => field.values.data.length !== length)) {
    throw new Error("Inconsistent lengths");
  }

  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    const numbers = [];
    for (const field of fields) {
      numbers.push(field.values.data[i]);
    }
    result.push(numbers);
  }

  return result;
}

const fields = [
  {
    name: "A",
    values: {
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    },
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    values: {
      data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    },
  },
];

const expected = [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]];

const actual = transpose(fields);

console.log(actual);
console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same array index and everything is static and not dynamic except the values, you can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  fields: [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: {
        data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
      }
    }
  ]
};

let out;

if (obj.fields[0].values.data.length === obj.fields[1].values.data.length) {
  const [d1, d2] = [obj.fields[0].values.data, obj.fields[1].values.data];
  out = d1.map((v, i) => [v, d2[i]]);
}

console.log(out);
```

Assumptions:

1. I used `obj` as the object that stores the response.
2. The structure is always `fields[X].values.data`.
3. There are only two indices: `fields[0].values.data` and `fields[1].values.data`.

**Output**

```
[ [1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list = [
    {
      name: "A",
      values: {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      values: {
        data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
      }
    },
    {
      name: "d",
      values: {
        data: [61232, 72324, 8, 92324, 10]
      }
    }
  ];
  
  let result = list.reduce((acc, {values: {data}}, i) => (
    data.forEach((value, j) => {
        acc[j] ??= [];
         acc[j][i] ??= value   
    }), acc
  ), []);
  
  console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```