# Array() vs new Array()

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the difference (if there is any) between

```
x = Array()
```

and

```
x = new Array()
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1) says:

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Array object. Thus the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments.

Answer (score 46):

You should use the literal `[]`. Reasons are outlined [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#array.constructor). Using the `Array()` constructor can be ambiguous, since it accepts either a `length` or a list of elements:

```
new Array(5)   // [ , , , , ]
new Array('5') // ['5']

[5]   // [5]
['5'] // ['5']
```

The reason you can use `Array` without the `new` operator is that internally it does a common trick with constructors:

```
function Thing(){
    if (!(this instanceof Thing)){
        return new Thing()
    }
    // ... define object
}
```

That is, if you call `Thing()` it will call `new Thing()` for you.

Comment: Actually, ```new Array(5)``` gives ```[,,,,]```

Comment: In ES5, To avoid this issue, you can use `Array.of`: "Array.of(7) creates an array with a single element, 7, whereas Array(7) creates an empty array with a length property of 7"

Answer (score 11):

Some facts that worth to mention:

```
Array === Array.prototype.constructor //true
```

and

`new Array()` does the same as `new Array` and `[]` as well

However, the result of calling a constructor is not necessarily equivalent to creating a new instance of an object. Example:

```
Foo = function(){}

x = Foo()   // undefined
y = new Foo // {}
```

So x and y can be different.

But if the Object itself is an Array you will get the same by definition, as mentioned earlier.

```
x = Array()   // []
y = new Array // []
```

Even if you pass one integer (telling the length)

```
x = Array(3)     // [empty × 3]
y = new Array(3) // [empty × 3]
```

or one non integer (telling the content)

```
x = Array(true)     // [true]
y = new Array(true) // [true]
```

or more parameters (telling the content)

```
x = Array(1,2,3)     // [1,2,3]
y = new Array(1,2,3) // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: that part about object literal `[]` being the same as `Array` and `new Array` is not true am afraid. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar

Comment: @azrahel you will get the same empty array using any of above expression (if `Array` is native), try: `{a:new Array,b:new Array(),c:[]}`

Comment: no you will not :) just read the link or documentation. Using object literal `[]` takes some shortcuts and internally does not execute some code that constructor does. If you don't care about performance or other edge case issues, sure, use whichever. If you do care though, you should know about differences, cause there are some. So what am saying is 'yes' you will get empty array in each case, but 'no' it s not going to be the same structurally/internally.

Comment: @azrahel It's no doubt that performance may differ, but technically each do the same thing. Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers

Comment: That `Array === Array.prototype.constructor` evaluates to `true` is completely uninteresting and holds for 99% of all JavaScript functions.

Comment: @Melab what is the 1 %?