# What the different between `new Array(n)` and `Array(n)`

Tags: javascript, arrays

What the different if both of them call the constructor "Array" and generate an object?

I know that we lost `this` if we create some object without `new`:

```
function Animal(name) {this.name = name}
var duck = Animal('duck'); // undefined
```

But how that works for `new Array(n)` and `Array(n)`?

Comment: A constructor can detect that it is not being called with `new` and force it to be called that way.  Some constructors do that.  Your constructor does not implement that.  The Array constructor does.

Comment: Similar was asked for CoffeeScript [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/coffeescript-array-vs-new-array)

Comment: When Array is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it also creates and initializes a new Array object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Check this [article](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/):

> You never need to use new Object() in JavaScript. Use the object
> literal {} instead. Similarly, don’t use new Array(), use the array
> literal [] instead. Arrays in JavaScript work nothing like the arrays
> in Java, and use of the Java-like syntax will confuse you.
>
> Do not use new Number, new String, or new Boolean. These forms produce
> unnecessary object wrappers. Just use simple literals instead.
>
> ...............................
>
> So the rule is simple: The only time we should use the new operator is
> to invoke a pseudoclassical Constructor function. When calling a
> Constructor function, the use of new is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Such behaviour for `Array` is described in spec.
You can achive the same behaviour like this

```
function Animal(name) {
  if(!(this instanceof Animal)) {
     return new Animal(name);
  } 
  this.name = name
}

var duck = Animal('duck'); //Animal {name: "duck"}
```

But a better idea would be to follow a simple code style convention that all functions starting with a captial letter are constructors and should be called with `new`. And set up a linter you prefer to check your code follows this rule.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses prototypal inheritance . When you use `new` command, It inherits from `Object` . Incase you want to inherit from an user defined object (e.g. Animal) you need to use `new Animal()` or without using `new` you can do it in following way.

```
   // Function object acts as a combination of a prototype 
     // to use for the new object and a constructor function to invoke:
     function Animal(name){
      this.name = name
     }

     var inheritFrom = function(parent, prop){
      // This is how you create object as a prototype of another object
      // var x = {} syntax can’t do this as it always set the newly
      //created object’s prototype to Object.prototype.

      var obj = Object.create(parent.prototype);
     // apply() method calls a function with a given this value 
     //and arguments provided as an array 

     parent.apply(obj, [prop]);
     return obj
    }
    var duck = inheritFrom(Animal, 'duck');
    console.log(duck.name);  // ‘duck’
```