# Difference between new Array() and Array() initialization syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why are these two statements the same in JavaScript?

```
var a = new Array(5); 
var a = Array(5);
```

Or, if they are not the same, what is different about them? Basically if I assign `a` to a different variable and mutate it, the values in the array change for each initialization in a similar way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array() vs new Array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/array-vs-new-array) and [What the different between `new Array(n)` and `Array(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263876)

Answer (score -1):

> Why are these two statements the same in JavaScript?
>
> ```
> var a = new Array(5);
> var a = Array(5);
> ```

That's just the way Array was designed. Not all constructors have this behavior, but the Array constructor's specification is such that it can be called either with `new` or without.

From the [ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array-constructor):

> 22.1.1The Array Constructor
>
> [...]
>
> - also creates and initializes a new Array object when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments.