# Difference between "new Array()" and "Array()"?

Tags: javascript

Array function could called as a function like `Array()` or as constructor `new Array()`. Is there any difference between these 2 calling method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/coffeescript-array-vs-new-array