# Initialize an array without `new` keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the difference between these two way of initializing an array in modern javascript environment (in ES6 spec) ?

```
const arr1 = new Array(3);
const arr2 = Array(3);
```

They look same running in Chrome console, and arr2 is also the instance of Array.

```
arr2 instanceof Array;
// true
```

Comment: Use the array literal syntax `[]`... oh you weren't asking for another option.

Comment: see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/coffeescript-array-vs-new-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/coffeescript-array-vs-new-array)

Comment: _"Thus the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments."_ --- From the ES2015 specs.