# How to 'repeat' an array n times

Tags: javascript, arrays

In python you can do:

```
arr = [1,2,3] * 3
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Is there a concise way of doing this in java script? The best I can think of is something like:

```
let arr2 = [...arr, ...arr, ...arr]
```

but if I wanted to do this 100 times it would be impractical. In python I would just multiply it by 100.

Comment: you could use the string `repeat` method, using `join` and `split` to convert the array to and from a strong?

Comment: @RobinZigmond would be problematic for an array of objects.

Comment: good point @Pointy,for some reason I was thinking as if it was an array of strings, when the OP is clearly talking about numbers. (It would "sort of" work for numbers though. Unlike for objects!)

Comment: Array(100*3).fill().map((v,i) => [1,2,3][i%3])

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var repeated = [].concat(... new Array(100).fill([1, 2, 3]));
```

That creates an array of a given length (100 here) and fills it with the array to be repeated (`[1, 2, 3]`).  That array is then spread as the argument list to `[].concat()`.

Oh wait just

```
var repeated = new Array(100).fill([1, 2, 3]).flat();
```

would be a little shorter.

Comment: I like this because it is a one liner that is easy to read and makes sense. Coming from python this feels more natural to me.

Comment: Note that [you can also omit the `new` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205709/965834).

Comment: @Jeto yes good point though I admit that that makes me irrationally uncomfortable

Comment: I wonder how efficient this is.

Comment: @MaxWaterman well if you want to do something to every element of an array, that's inherently a linear-time operation.

Comment: @Pointy sure, but is it linear? It depends on how it is implemented. It seems to me it makes an array of pointers to new array of length 3, and then it goes through, yet again, to flatten it into a one dimensional array. As I said, I wonder if it is cleverer than that, or not. The Array.from() solution seems to be more obviously only a single traversal (make memory for the array, then assign to it).

Comment: @MaxWaterman going through a list a fixed number of times is still O(n).  `Array.from()` is also going to (internally) make a linear pass through the list.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, ok, linear, fair enough - but it seems to go through the (different?) arrays twice, while it isn't clear to me that Array.from() would go through twice (hence my question), or just once. I'll take your word for it if you think Nina's Array.from() method does two passes...not sure why it would but there you go - JavaScript is a funny animal.

Comment: Note that 100 is not the 'length of the result array'. It is the number of times the supplied array gets "repeated"

Answer (score 8):

You could create an array with the wanted length and map the values.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    result = Array.from({ length: 3 * array.length }, (_, i) => array[i % array.length]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: IMO, this one is the most efficient and seems to equate to a malloc followed by a single loop over the array elements. Other solutions seem to involve multiple loops over the array elements.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array with a length of the multiplier, where each item contains the original array. Then use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert to a single array:

```js
const multiplyArray = (arr, length) => 
  Array.from({ length }, () => arr).flat()

const arr = [1,2,3]
const arr2 = multiplyArray(arr, 3)

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing the Array.from() method to my attention, it will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

One quick way is joining the array, repeating it using string.repeat(), then splitting it and finally using ES6 Spreads

The other answer are probably better. This is just a simpel one-liner.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let res = [...arr.join("").repeat(3).split("").map(Number)];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain and Simple:

```js
    var n=4; //times //put 100
    var array = [1,2,3];
    var newarray = [];
    while(n--){ var newarray = newarray.concat(array); }
    alert(newarray);
```

Comment: `console.log(var);` this should probably be `console.log(array);`, still wouldn't produce the wanted result

Comment: @LucaKiebel Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Now it works just fine ;-) By ovwerwriting `array` before you always doubled the array in size.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function fillArray(value, len) {
    if (len == 0) return [];
        var a = [value];
        while (a.length * 2 <= len) a = a.concat(a);
    if (a.length < len) a = a.concat(a.slice(0, len - a.length));
        return a;
}
```

It doubles the array in each iteration, so it can create a really large array with few iterations.

Comment: This doesn't generate the desired output or meet the requirement of "concise".