# Create an array alternating between 2 different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create an array alternating between 2 different values with a predetermined length.

Example:

```
conts value1 = 1;
const value2 = 2; 
cont length = 6; 

//desired output
const array1 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
```

Comment: First, it looks like you have an error in your code "const". Second, could you add the resulting values and the expected values to see what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the array using `Array.from` with the desired length and `map` it to have the desired values :

```js
const value1 = 1;
const value2 = 2; 
const length = 6; 

const result = Array.from({ length }).map((e, ndx) => ndx % 2 ? value2 : value1); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var repeated = new Array(3).fill([1, 2]).flat();
```

Or more general:

```
function repeat(n, value){
    return new Array(n).fill(value).flat();
}

result = repeat(3, [1, 2]);
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54935305/4628597

Answer (score 0):

An easy beginner solution would be something like this:

```
function createArray(value1, value2, length){
    var array = new Array()
    for(var i=0; i<length;i++){ 
          if(i%2 == 0){
           array.push(value1);
          }else{
           array.push(value2);
          }
    return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will dissect this a bit more to see how you did it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of values in the wanted order and use a closure over the index of the values array adjusted by taking the remainder with the length of the values array.

```js
const values = [1, 2],
      length = 6,
      result = Array.from({ length }, (i => _ => values[i++ % values.length])(0)); 

console.log(result);
```