# Comparison of the two situations when the constructor is called without the new keyword

Tags: javascript, constructor

```js
function Person(name, age, gender) {
  this.name = name; // run
}

function PersonSafe(name) {
  if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee))
    return new PersonSafe(name)

  this.name = name; // run
}

var qux = Person('qux');
console.log('Person qux: ', qux);
console.log('[[global]] name: ', name);

var quxSafe = PersonSafe('qux');
console.log('PersonSafe qux: ', quxSafe);
```

[image]

A comparison of the two situations when the `constructor` is called without the `new` keyword.
I don't know **why the results of running the two codes are different**.
The `body` of`Person()`and`PersonSafe()`functions are different, 
but the line (`this.name = name;`) that`qux` and `quxSafe` will execute is the same. 
**So... Why are the results different?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/array-vs-new-array if you are trying to find out the difference between using new and without new.

Comment: Calling a function without `new` just executes it like any other function. `Person` doesn't contain a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Tick20 Hi thanks for your comment. But, the two objects are created without `new` keyword.

Comment: @Tick20 That's not really a good example since it's specifically about `Array`.

Comment: @JLRishe Hi thanks for your comment. But the line `this.name = name;` of `PersonSafe` that `quxSafe` will run is also doesn't return anything.

Comment: @snaag `PersonSafe` contains a `return` statement. It recursively calls itself using `new` if it wasn't invoked using `new`. That's the difference.

Comment: @JLRishe Oh my..... Oh I was really really really dumb.... Wow.. I understand it!! Wow.. Thank you.. ha ha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function as a constructor (here, `Person`), an object is created (an empty object whose internal prototype is the constructor function's prototype - `Person.prototype` here), and *that object* that was just created is what the `this` value will point to inside the function. That object will also be implicitly returned at the end of the constructor.

In contrast, when you *don't* use `new`, no such object is created; you're just calling an ordinary function, and the `this` value inside it will depend on the calling context of the function. Here, because there's no calling context (the function being called is not part of an object), the `this` inside the function will either be the global object (in the case of sloppy mode), or `undefined` (in the case of strict mode).

So `var qux = Person('qux');` runs `this.name = name`, where `this` is the global object.

With `PersonSafe`, you're checking that the `this` is an instance of the constructor (that the `this` has an internal prototype of the constructor's prototype) - if called without `new`, that test will fail, since `this` will be either the global object or `undefined`.

Note that `arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode, and strict mode should nearly always be used. Consider replacing with `new.target` instead:

```js
function PersonSafe(name) {
    if(!(new.target))
        return new PersonSafe(name)

    this.name = name; // run
}

var quxSafe = PersonSafe('qux');
console.log('PersonSafe qux: ',quxSafe);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why this is different is caused by "new" keyword which means that function will be treated as object and it will get **proto** property assigned.

Also this variable will be pointed to newly created object.

Here is good description: [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)