# JavaScript - random multiple of 20 between 0 - 580

Tags: javascript, random

In Javascript, how do I create a random even number multiplied by 20 between 0 - 580?

E.g.: 220, 360, 180, 0 (min), 400, 200, 580 (max)

Comment: What've you come up with so far?

Comment: A multiple of 20 is always even.

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*60;
But it mustn't generate 600!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378885/1398531

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want increments of 20, so what you really need is an integer in the range 0 to 29, and then multiply with 20. Example:

```
var max = (580/20) + 1;
var result = 20 * (Math.floor(Math.random())*max)
```

We are adding one to `max`, because Math.random() is a uniformly distributed number between (inclusive 0) and (exclusive 1), so since we use Math.floor, the maximum must be 1 larger.

Answer (score 3):

This way creates a random number, then rounds it down to the nearest multiple:

When you need ***0 <= randomMultiple <= max***

```
var random = Math.random() * (580 + 20);
randomMultiple = random - (random % 20);
```

When you need ***0 <= randomMultiple < max***

```
var random = Math.random() * 580;
randomMultiple = random - (random % 20);
```

Comment: Oh my God! This way is so beautiful, I would've never found it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use a principle like this:  [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/random-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Keeping in mind that if you want your max result to be 580, then the maximum integer you want to multiply by 20 would be 29 (or 580/20).  Then just add some logic to make sure the integer is even.

Ta da!

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
var result = parseInt(Math.random()*30)*20;
```

29*20 = 580

Math.random() return [0..1)

result between 0..580, step by 20

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic javascript one-liner that can be used for any range, and any multiple.

Essentially, what we are trying to do here is figure out a range, 0 to *N*, which when multiplied by our given *multiple* stays within the range [0,*max-min*].

In this case *N*, is simply, *(max - min)/multiple*, or *range/multiple*.

Once we have *N*, we can use Math.random() to get a random number between 0-*N*, and multiply it with multiple. Next, we just add *min*.

We assume that *min* and *max* are already multiples of multiple.

Note the additional +1 to the input of Math.random() is because Math.random() returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (**exclusive**). So, Math.random() can never return 1. If we didn't account for that we would never be able to include the max number in our results.

```js
/*
 * Returns a random number within range [min,max]
 *
 * min and max must be multiples of multiple
 * (note that 0 is a multiple of all integers)
 */
function randomMultiple (min, max, multiple) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (((max - min)/multiple)+1)) * multiple + min;
}

console.log(randomMultiple(0, 580, 20));
```