# Is there a techique to not have cases repeat when using Math.random()?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple cases that are under `Math.random` but sometimes they repeat. It looks a little unprofessional. Is there a way to always go to another random case?

Comment: random numbers can repeat.. what number range are you looking at

Comment: Define "cases".  Use-cases?  Switch-case?  `Math.random` is not the best random/pseudo-random generator out there, so if you need more randomness, you're going to have another way to implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating unique random numbers (integers) between 0 and 'x'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378870/generating-unique-random-numbers-integers-between-0-and-x). Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100,

Comment: Which random numbers do you need? `INT` or `DECIMAL`, From-to?

Comment: Hint: fill array and shuffle.

Comment: You might be more interested in a solution without `Math.Random`: create an array of integers from the range that you'd like, shuffle it and every time extract the next item.

Comment: Can you rely on a server side implementation of Random() instead? Typically server side frameworks have better implementations than JS

Comment: I'm trying to load 15 different htmls in an iframe from a button outside of the iframe.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I'm using switch cases.

Comment: `Math.floor((Math.random()*15)+1);`

Comment: Define them as a named function and then call them with different parameters? Don't really know what you mean to be honest. Jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating what Nemanja Boric says in his comment: Fill an array and shuffle.

Here is an example: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

```
    var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    newArray = shuffle(myArray);
```

newArray will be something like ['3','8','1','9','6','4','5','2','7']