# How do I select a button randomly with WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am testing price comparisons web application and I would like to randomly select one of the "Apply Now" buttons. 
I had tried: (and other similar scenario example from stack)

But every time it select 1st Apply now button. I would like to select different button every time. 
HTML:

```
<div class="applyNowButtonContainer">
<a class="join-now" data-productid="******" data-excessid="******" data-href="/XXXXX/ApplyNow_prepare.action?rank=1&hash=onclick="Within.joinNow(this);" href="javascript:void(0)">Apply Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what language r u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// get all links by xpath
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Apply Now')]));

// select a random one
Random gen = new Random();
WebElement link = links.get(gen.nextInt(list.size()));

link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Query all buttons by type or class and use random index on the array of buttons

Here is how you can get random index within the range: [Generating unique random numbers (integers) between 0 and 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378870/generating-unique-random-numbers-integers-between-0-and-x)